# Checking if a collection is empty in Java: which is the best method?

Tags: java, collections, is-empty

I have two ways of checking if a List is empty or not

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listName))
```

and

```
if (listName != null && listName.size() != 0)
```

My arch tells me that the former is better than latter. But I think the latter is better.

Can anyone please clarify it?

Comment: why do you think "latter" is better?

Comment: Why not `listname.isEmpty()` ? `isEmpty` is a method in the Collection interface

Comment: why do you say latter is better? just because it checks null?

Comment: collection interface provide isEmpty() method for empty check.both ways are better u can go with any one as per choice.

Comment: I think personal flavor has a way in this. CollectionUtils does 2 things in one call so it is easier for you as a developer. The latter gives you as a developer a little more work however you do save the computer a push of the collection ref on the stack and the whole stack work around it. Performance-wise, the latter will be slightly faster. Not that you'll notice.

Comment: Hi there... am I the only one seeing this as a matter of legibility? The first one is obviously better for making the code way more legible. Which sentence makes you **think less** when reading that, the resolution of two operations combined with an _and_ or simply reading _isNotEmpty_ ?? We can talk long about the performance benefits of the latter, but as a matter of error proneness, the former is much more robust.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You should *absolutely* use `isEmpty()`. Computing the `size()` of an arbitrary list could be expensive. Even validating whether it has any elements *can* be expensive, of course, but there's no optimization for `size()` which can't *also* make `isEmpty()` faster, whereas the reverse is not the case.

For example, suppose you had a linked list structure which *didn't* cache the size (whereas `LinkedList<E>` *does*). Then `size()` would become an O(N) operation, whereas `isEmpty()` would still be `O(1)`.

Additionally of course, using `isEmpty()` states what you're actually interested in more clearly.

Comment: While the `List.size()==0` vs `List.isEmpty()` performance argument is correct, this does not answer to the question regarding the use of Apache commons-collections `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` or `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()`

Comment: LinkedLists implement `isEmpty` as `return size() == 0;`, though.

Comment: @user3932000: Sure, I'd expect that to be the case for any implementation that *does* know the size in a cheap way

Answer (score 74):

`CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty` checks if your collection is not null and not empty. This is better comparing to double check but only if you have this Apache library in your project. If you don't then use:

```
if(list != null && !list.isEmpty())
```

Comment: The other advantage of using Apache commons-collections `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` (or `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty`) is that your `if` condition has less branches, so it is easier to reach a good branch coverage in your tests. For example, Sonarqube reports a 75% coverage at best for `if (list==null || list.isEmpty())` because you cannot have a list which is null and not empty at the same time.

Comment: @JulienKronegg I don't think I agree. `list == null` and `list.isEmpty()` are two different use-cases and we should have test cases defined for each condition. One test case should evaluate the case when list is null and other should evaluate the case when list is *non-null* but *empty*. Just reaching coverage is not the true intention of unit tests.

Answer (score 15):

`if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listName))`

Is the same as:

`if(listName != null && !listName.isEmpty())`

In first approach `listName` can be null and null pointer exception will not be thrown. In second approach you have to check for null manually. First approach is better because it requires less work from you. Using `.size() != 0` is something unnecessary at all, also i learned that it is slower than using `.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 13):

Unless you are already using CollectionUtils I would go for `List.isEmpty()`, less dependencies.

Performance wise CollectionUtils will be a tad slower. Because it basically follows the same logic but has additional overhead.

So it would be readability vs. performance vs. dependencies. Not much of a big difference though.

Comment: 20 years as a developer and the habit of using CollectionUtils made me lazy. Didn't even notice the standard List.isEmpty()! Never too old to learn. Thanks man! I will change this attitide of mine :-D

Comment: List.isEmpty() is not the same as CollectionUtils.isEmpty()!  The latter will handle the case where the collection is null, the former will throw an NPE.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the Apache common utilities in your project rather use the first one. Because its shorter and does exactly the same as the latter one. There won't be any difference between both methods but how it looks inside the source code.

Also a empty check using

```
listName.size() != 0
```

Is discouraged because all collection implementations have the

```
listName.isEmpty()
```

function that does exactly the same.

So all in all, if you have the Apache common utils in your classpath anyway, use

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listName))
```

in any other case use

```
if(listName != null && listName.isEmpty())
```

You will not notice any performance difference. Both lines do exactly the same.

Comment: There are collections where the `size()` method is O(n). It's generally expected that all `isEmpty()` implementations will be O(1).

Answer (score 7):

Apache Commons' CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(Collection) is a NULL-SAFE check

Returns TRUE is the Collection/List is not-empty and not-null
Returns FALSE if the Collection is Null

Example:

```
List<String> properties = new ArrayList();
...
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(properties)) {
  // process the list
} else {
 // list is null or empty
}
```

Refer:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 2):

A good example of where this matters in practice is the [`ConcurrentSkipListSet` implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) in the JDK, which states:

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is not a constant-time operation.

This is a clear case where `isEmpty()` is much more efficient than checking whether `size()==0`.

You can see why, intuitively, this might be the case in some collections. If it's the sort of structure where you have to traverse the whole thing to count the elements, then if all you want to know is whether it's empty, you can stop as soon as you've found the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
isEmpty()

      Returns true if this list contains no elements.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first one. It is clear to see right away what it does. I dont think the null check is necessary here.

Comment: but you can also write a util of your own that will do the same that the second option does. Choose between options should be reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Use **CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Collection coll)**

Null-safe check if the specified collection is empty.
Null returns true.

**Parameters:**
coll - the collection to check, may be null

**Returns:**
true if empty or null

Answer (score 0):

The org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils isEmpty() method is used to check any collections(List, Set, etc.) are empty or not. It checks for null as well as size of collections. The CollectionUtils isEmpty() is a static method, which accepts Collection as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
table.column = ANY(ARRAY[ :canEmptyArrayParameter ]::BIGINT[])
```

It helps me to check empty parameter of array

this parameter can be Collections.emptyList();

Answer (score -9):

To Check collection is empty, you can use method: .count(). Example:

```
DBCollection collection = mMongoOperation.getCollection("sequence");
    if(collection.count() == 0) {
        SequenceId sequenceId = new SequenceId("id", 0);
        mMongoOperation.save(sequenceId);
    }
```