# Best way to check collections not null & null conditions

Tags: java, collections

we use collections like ArrayList,hashmap & many more.

Number of times we have check condition like whether list is null or not.

We have many ways to chek whether our collection is  null or not.

Different ways.

```
1. if(list==null)
2. if(list.size()==0)
3. if(list.isEmpty())
```

Also sometimes we also need to check whether list is not null , so we normally check it by these ways

```
1. if(list!=null)
2. if(list.size()>0)
3. if(!list.isEmpty())
```

> Which is best condition  or do we need to make some combination of
>   these considering performance of program execution?

Answer (score 9):

Best combination would be

```
if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty()){

        //Yeah ,do something
}
```

One for null check, and then any thing there or not check

Comment: In a bad world, this is the best possible check. In a good world, make sure that the list can never be null in the first place.

Comment: As some have pointed out, returning nulls is a bad idea for collections; however, you are not always in control of the data provided to you, such as with 3rd party libraries and web service endpoints. Sure you could require the data, but that isn't always the most user friendly option. When you don't control the input data, you only have 2 options, validate the data exists and throw an error otherwise, or check for the data as stated in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
1. if(list!=null)
```

You should make sure that is never the case!!

Read [Effective Java 2nd Edition by Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
**Item 43: Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls**

> [...] In summary, there is no reason ever to return null from an array- or
>   collection-valued method instead of returning an empty array or
>   collection. The null-return idiom is likely a holdover from the C
>   programming language, in which array lengths are returned separately
>   from actual arrays. In C, there is no advantage to allocating an array
>   if zero is returned as the length.

In short, let your methods return [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) instead of null and you've got one thing less to worry about.

```
2. if(list.size()>0)
3. if(!list.isEmpty())
```

That depends. For a simple collection such as ArrayList, they are equivalent. But what if your Collection is actually a live view of a Database query? Calling size() might me a very expensive operation, whereas isEmpty() will always be O(1). I'd say use isEmpty().

Also see Jon Skeet's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11152624/342852

Answer (score 3):

In [Java8](https://leanpub.com/whatsnewinjava8/read) you can use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to handle null cases properly. For example, both lists `animalsNull` and `animalWithNullElements` would be properly handled by the function `filterList`:

```
List<String> animalsNull = null;

List<String> animalWithNullElements = new ArrayList<String>();
        animalWithNullElements.add(0, null);
        animalWithNullElements.add(1, "Guybrush Threepwood");
        animalWithNullElements.add(2, null);

private static List<String> filterList(List<String> animals) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(animals)
               .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
               .stream()
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Looks nice but it feels odd to use Optional with Collection. I have read several sources talking about this as not good practice. wdyt?

Comment: Hi @Rafael, can you please post the sources?

Comment: You can find an interesting discussion here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional

Comment: Thanks, it's a good thread but refers to a different use of Optional. Please notice that in the ink you pasted the Optional is no the element inside the collection. When in my code example the Optional is on the list itself.

Comment: You are right. I missed the source. Here is a different one that speaks about using optional as Collection wrapper as not good -> http://dolszewski.com/java/java-8-optional-use-cases/ where

Comment: This one is a different case as well. In the article you mentioned they discussing using a type of Optional<List<...>> as a return value and I'm not suggesting at all.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do. If you want to be sure that a list exist AND has some elements then you would use

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())
```

If I may give some advice, while returning collections, return by default an empty collection. That way you will avoid nulls.

Answer (score 2):

> Number of times we have check condition like whether list is null or not.

For a start, a `null` collection and an empty collection are **different things**.  If you need to test if a collection is `null` you need a *different* test to if you are trying to test if the collection is empty.

Secondly, if a collection could be either `null` or empty (and they "mean" the same thing, per your application design) then you have a problem in your design.  You should most likely represent ... whatever it is you are trying to represent ... one way, and not either / both ways.

Thirdly, it is generally best to use an empty collection rather than a `null`, because you can treat an empty and non-empty collection uniformly.  By contrast, a `null` *always* needs to be handled as a special case.  (And if you forget to handle the `null` case, then you've got a potential for `NullPointerExceptions`.)

---

Having said that ...

> Which is best condition or do we need to make some combination of these considering performance of program execution?

If you really need to deal with the case of a `null`, then you've no choice but to test for `null`.

For `isEmpty()` versus `size() == 0`:

- the two predicates should give the same answer (unless you have an infinite lazy collection ...), but
- in some cases `isEmpty()` *could* be faster, at least in theory.

The latter depends on the implementation of the collection type: specifically, on whether the `size()` method needs to *count* the collection elements.  (I don't think that any of the standard collection classes have this property, but that's not to say that you won't find some class that does ...)

So the optimal predicate is most likely either:

```
 c != null && !c.isEmpty()
```

or

```
 !c.isEmpty()
```

depending on whether you (really) need to cater for nulls.

And the obvious corollary is that your application is likely to be more efficient ... as well as simpler and more robust ... if you *don't* use `null` to represent empty collections.  (If you need immutable empty collection objects, you can get them for free from methods / statics defined by the `Collections` class.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful util class called `CollectionUtils` from Apache `commons-collections` bundle. With using it the code will look like:

`if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(collection))`

It looks nice and under the hood it has the same invocation:

`public static boolean isEmpty(Collection coll) {
        return coll == null || coll.isEmpty();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

`null` means `list` is initialized with null. `null` list `size` or `isEmpty` will throw `NullPointerException`. But,  not null `list` can be empty or size==0

```
(list!=null) != (list.size()==0)
```

size==0 and isEmpty is equivalent.

```
(list.size()==0) ==  list.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple approaches to handle this:

1: If code makes sure that collection cannot be `null` by initializing it either in constructor or as field initializaiton then caller need not to ideally check for `null` everywhere. Only `isEmpty` check should suffice:

```
private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //or in constructor
```

// caller can then safely use

```
if(numbers.isEmpty)
```

2: Alternatively write a utility method to have `null` and `empty` check, no need for `size` check as it already happens inside `isEmpty` call. Use this utility method elsewhere in code.

```
public static boolean empty(Collection<?> col) {
   return col == null || col.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your program structure. For example, I have a helper class called `ArrayUtils`, in which I have an API that looks like this:

```
public static <E> boolean isEmpty(final Collection<E> collection)
{
    return collection == null || collection.isEmpty();
}
```

I use this one when I know that I may get a `null` list, but when I'm absolutely sure it's not `null`, I use only `if ( collection.isEmpty )`. Improves code readability, too.

`collection.size() > 1` is redundant, because you have the other APIs at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

If it you are owner of the codebase, I would avoid using such logic at all.
Instead try to follow the model when your collection supplier can't return null but has a reference to Collections.emptyXXX or just regular empty container empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two predicates as below :

```
public static final Predicate<String> NULL_OR_EMPTY = (in) -> null == in || "".equals(in);

public static final Predicate<List<String>> STRING_LIST_NULL_OR_EMPTY = (strList) ->  strList.stream().filter(NULL_OR_EMPTY).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 0;
```