# Java 8 Optional usage

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I recently found out about the Optional type in java 8 and started using it in my latest project. I used it like:

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private Optional<String> mobile;
    public User(int id, String email, Optional<String> mobile){
       ...
    }
    public int id(){...}
    public int email(){...}
    public Optional<String> mobile(){...}
}
```

Today i was exploring more about Optional when i came across posts which clearly stated that using Optional at places other than return type is a bad practice. After verifying this from multiple sources i changed my code like:

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    public User(int id, String email, String mobile){
       ...
    }
    public int id(){...}
    public int email(){...}
    public Optional<String> mobile(){
        return Optional.ofNullable(mobile);
    }
}
```

Is this an accepatable solution? Specifically i changed some method signatures taking in Optional to T and then inside the method I converted T to Optional.ofNullable(t) so that i can use methods like ifPresent, orElse, filter, map etc.

Comment: What sources do you have saying that having Optional as a field is bad practice? And what are the drawbacks?

Comment: @aioobe Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-java8-optional?rq=1 The argument is that it is a bad java practice, we should use method overloading, constructor overloading instead of taking in Optional parameters.

Comment: Yeah. That answer makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your alternative implementation of returning `Optional.ofNullable` is good.

I had to make this change myself when making a class `Serializable`. As Stuart Marks says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/276052), it adds little value to make the field optional (you can always use `mobile()` instead of `mobile` to get the `Optional` view of the field).

Comment: I was led astray initially because i referred to this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html which clearly uses optional fields. What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: I don't have that much experience, but I can't see why it would be bad practice. If your class has many null-checks an optional field may improve readability/maintainability. On the other hand, if one has many null-checks, then perhaps one should split the class in two. If you, in your `User`/`mobile` example had several statements such as `if (mobile == null) {...} else {...}` and the logic in fact depended on whether mobile was null or not, it would perhaps make sense to have two `User` subclasses: `UserWithMobile` and `UserWithoutMobile`.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that this is bad practice, now internally it's possible to access the the `mobile` field and generate a `null pointer`.  So why not make it impossible by storing it as an optional.

Comment: @mogronalol, refer to Stuart Marks answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/276052).