# Avoid isPresent() and get() in control logic

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

Is there a prettier way of doing the following in Java 8, avoiding `isPresent` and `get`?

```
void doStuff(String someValue, Optional<Boolean> doIt) {
    if (doIt.isPresent()) {
        if (doIt.get()) {
            trueMethod(someValue);
        } else {
            falseMethod(someValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using `map`, without success.  But I probably didn't try hard enough?

Comment: Probably it's not a good design to use `Optional` as method parameter. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/4856258) by OpenJDK developer.

Comment: I agree with @Tagir Valeev. I expect that, since this function does nothing when `doIt` is empty, you've given us an oversimplified version of the function.  The best option is probably to provide an override.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ifPresent` instead of `isPresent` and `get` :

```
void doStuff(String someValue, Optional<Boolean> doIt) {
    doIt.ifPresent (b -> {
                             if (b) 
                                 trueMethod(someValue);  
                             else
                                 falseMethod(someValue);
                         });
}
```

EDIT: fixed my code, since you can't use the ternary operator if `trueMethod` and `falseMethod` don't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the functional approach using `map`:

```
Function<Boolean, Void> logic = isTrue -> {
  if (isTrue) trueMethod(someValue);
  else falseMethod(someValue);
  return null;
};
doIt.map(logic);
```

However, it is **really ugly**, mostly because of your "not-very-functional" `trueMethod`/`falseMethod`, which both return `void` (leading to the ugly `return null`).