# Is get() on Java's Optional hazardous?

Tags: java, functional-programming

In functional languages it is common to use pattern matching on optional types:

```
let result = match myOptional with 
             | Some x -> x * 2
             | None -> 0
```

This is very helpful to the programmer, since the compiler checks that the pattern matches are complete.

However, in the examples for Java's `Optional` that I have seen, `isPresent` and `get` are used instead:

```
Integer result;
if (myOptional.isPresent()) {
    result = myOptional.get() * 2;
} else {
    result = 0;
}
```

To me, this defeats the purpose of `Optional`. The compiler does no checking to ensure that the both branches of the `if` are implemented correctly, and the resulting code has no extra guarantees than the equivalent using `null`.

This design choice discourages safety, so why does the standard library provide a `get` function instead of just `match`?

Comment: What "correctness" do you want the compiler to check for? Definite assignment ensures you've assigned `result` before you use it; I can't think what else you want. (I may just be failing in imagination here...)

Comment: Yes, it helps the programmer avoid NPEs.

Comment: "it helps the programmer avoid NPEs" But what NPEs would you get in this case?

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860584/avoid-ispresent-and-get-in-control-logic

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778248/null-check-vs-optional-is-present-check

Comment: Those questions are related, but what I want to understand is *why* the API was designed this way. I assume that the Java designers know what they are doing, so there is probably a good reason for it!

Comment: "This design choice discourages safety" What alternative design do you think would be better? What is *actually* unsafe about this? Please give a specific example which illustrates the problems you envisage.

Comment: @AndyTurner the F# snippet above is safer because it ensures that `result` is always initialized. Leaving off either of the two cases is a compile-time error.

Comment: @sdgfsdh [definite assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html) ensures the same thing. [Try it](http://ideone.com/O0MkYJ): leave either of the branches out, see if it still compiles if you use `result` somewhere. This is not specifically to do with `Optional`, though.

Comment: @AndyTurner So it does! Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the F# snippet above is safer because it ensures that result is always initialized. Leaving off either of the two cases is a compile-time error.

It would be in Java too: Java uses [definite assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html) to ensure that local and final variables are initialized.

Note that this has nothing to do with `Optional`, specifically: any time the compiler can determine that such a variable may not have been initialized before it is used, it will raise an error.

For example:

```
int result;
if (someCondition) {
  result = 0;
}
System.out.println(result);  // result might not have been initialized.
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/5AVg6o)

[<kbd>Ideone demo, using OP's code</kbd>](http://ideone.com/O0MkYJ)

So there isn't really anything "unsafe" about this design (with regard to assignment of local or final variables).

Comment: Good job trying to understand what the OP meant!

Comment: Don't agree. Initialization is only a part of the picture. The compiler cannot make sure that the programmer didn't accidentally mix up the `if` branches. The author could write `if (!opt.isPresent()) { result = opt.get() * 2; }` and this would fail at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

This is done with [the `Optional::map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Your example could be written:

```
Integer result = myOptional.map(i -> i * 2).orElse(0);
```

With regards to the `get` method, there has been [a discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040484.html) to deprecate it - I'm not sure if a decision has been reached yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally you should avoid calling `get()`. However, sometimes this is the only satisfactory solution because capabilities of lambda-expressions are rather limited. Here is the list of things that lambdas can not do:

- Throw checked exceptions if a method does not have a corresponding `throws` declaration
- Modify mutable variables in an outer scope
- Break from a cycle (or continue)
- Return from a method

Consider this example:

```
if (opt.isPresent()) {
    int value = opt.get();
    if (value == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Catastrophical error!");
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since `Consumer` does not support checked exceptions, you cannot rewrite this code snippet with lambdas in a simple way.

Other disadvantages of lambdas:

- Longer stack traces
- Harder to debug
- Require memory allocation (important for performance-critical applications)

So, the final answer is: try to write correct and functional code. Since `get()` can potentially affect the correctness of your code, avoid using it as much as possible. But, if your run to limitations of lambdas, don't rack your brain and just use `get()`. Your colleagues will thank you when they see a readable snippet of code instead of an ugly workaround which modifies outer mutable variables or throw a checked exception inside a lambda.