# Java8 optional and null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, java-8, option-type

I have following code:

```
final Optional<List<ServiceAttributeValue>> attributeValueList = Optional.<Product> of(product)
         .map(Product::getServiceAttributes)
         .map(ServiceAttributeMap::getMap)
         .map((v) -> (ServiceAttribute) v.get(attributeV.getAttributeString()))
         .map((c) -> (List<ServiceAttributeValue>) c.getValueList());
```

do I need to add check if v is null?

Comment: You probably don't need the `.<Product>` and you don't need the prentheses around single argument lambdas (you can replace `(v) ->` with `v ->`).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code is buggy. You using Optional to avoid NPE where your code will throw NPE if product is null. You should use `Optional.ofNullable` instead.

```
Optional.ofNullable(product)
```

and the answer is no, the third map will not get executed if `ServiceAttributeMap::getMap` returns null

Comment: Why do you think his `product` *can* be null? Author did not say so. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31696485/4856258).