# Is there a real reason to use Optional.of()?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696485/why-use-optional-of-over-optional-ofnullable) why `Optional.of()` should be used over `Optional.ofNullable()`, but the answer didn't satisfy me at all, so I ask slightly different:

If you are SURE that your method does not return `null`, why should you use `Optional` at all? As far as I know, the more or less only purpose of it is to remind the "user of a method", that he might have to deal with `null`-values. If he does not have to deal with `null`-values, why should he be bothered with an `Optional`?

I ask, because I recently made my service-layer return Optionals instead of nulls (in certain situations). I used `Optional.of()` and was highly confused when it threw a NullPointer.

A sample of what I did:

```
Optional valueFromDB = getUserById("12");
User user = valueFromDB.get(); 

.....

public Optional<User> getUserById(String id) {
  //...
  return Optional.of(userRepository.findOne(id)); // NullPointerException!
}
```

If null is not possible, I don't see why one would wrap it in an `Optional`. The dude in the linked answer said "well, if a NullPointer happens, it happens right away!" But do I really want that? If the sole purpose of an `Optional` is, to remind the programmer who gets such an object, to keep `null` in mind (he HAS to unwrap it), why should I want to have `NullPointerException` at wrapping-time?

---

**Edit:** I needed to edit the question, because it got marked as duplicate, even though I already linked said question from the start. I also did explain, why the answer did not satisfy me, but now I need to edit my text with an explanation.
But here is some appendix to what I want to ask, since I got 5 answers and everyone answers a different case, but none fully covered what I try to ask here:

**Is there a reason, that Optional.of(null) is impossible and they specifically added Optional.ofNullable() for the null case?**

Using streams should not be the problem with my idea of the implementation. 
I got a lot of insight from your answers, thanks for that. But the real question has not been answered until now, as far as I can tell/read/understand.
Maybe I should have asked: "What if we remove the `Optional.of()` method and only allow `Optional.ofNullable()` in Java 9, would there be any problem except backwards-compatibility?"

Comment: The sole purpose of `Optional` is to clearly indicate that there might be no result. When used properly you don't need to do `null` checks and yu can do `user.ifPresent(doAMethod())` or can use it in streams and other JDK8 APIs without having to check for `null` elements. So when used properly it can reduce the amount of null checking in your code.

Comment: @M.Deinum: `ifPresent` is basically a null-check. :P It just looks better and is more convenient to use. I get the thing with the streams though, but that has nothing to do with the question itself. I didn't question Optionals, I did question, if `Optional.of()` is useful. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: If your method is not meant to return null, on one side I agree you don’t want to return an `Optional`. On the other hand you do want to be informed if one day the value you are going to return is null by error. I would use a good old `assert` statement for that.

Answer (score 15):

You are mixing up the API design rationale with knowledge within a particular implementation code. It’s perfectly possible that a method declares to return an `Optional`, because the value might be absent, while at a certain code location within the method, it is known to be definitely present. I.e.

```
String content;
public Optional<String> firstMatch(String pattern) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(content);
    return m.find()? Optional.of(m.group()): Optional.empty();
}
```

This method’s return type denotes a `String` that might be absent, while at the code locations creating an `Optional` instance, it is known whether the value is present or absent. It’s not about detecting a `null` value here.

Likewise, within the Stream API methods `findFirst()` and `findAny()`, it will be known at one point, whether there is a matching element, whereas supporting the conversion of its presence to absence in case of a matching `null` element is explicitly unsupported and supposed to raise a `NullPointerException`, [per specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--). Therefore, `Optional.of` will be used to return the matching element, which you can easily recognize in the stack trace when using `Stream.of((Object)null) .findAny();`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696485/why-use-optional-of-over-optional-ofnullable#comment51344170_31696584) for another example…

Answer (score 11):

The other reason to use `Optional.of(value)` when you know that `value` can't be null is that if you want to do additional filtering operations on that `Optional`.

For example:

```
public static long getPageSizeFrom(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return Optional.of(request.getParameter("pageSize"))
                   .filter(StringUtils::isNumeric)
                   .map(Long::valueOf)
                   .filter(page::hasPageSize)
                   .orElse(page::getDefaultPageSize)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right with your opinion that you should not use Optional if you are sure that you always have a return-value.

**But** your method is not sure, that it always returns a value!

Think of an call to *getUserById(-1)*. There is (normally) no User with this id, and your *userRepository* will return *null*.

So in this case you should use Optional.ofNullable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-

Comment: Yeah but the question is, why `Optional.of()` exists at all.

Comment: @codepleb, exactly! I had the same question. So I tried running a line of code with `Optional.of()`. It throws an exception at this line itself. So I understand that if a field is not meant to be NULL, then declare it with `Optional.of()`. If it's null, an exception is thrown at this declaration and not at any other method calls on this object. Which informs a developer that the object is supposed to have a value, doesn't matter of its usage further. In case of normal declaration, you will get a NPE when you operate on it.

EDIT: Lol, noticed that I'm too early to comment :D

Answer (score 2):

Optional is one of those things that has been imported from functional programming languages and dumped into the laps of OO and procedural programmers [without much](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) [background explanation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)...which has caused much pain and hand wringing.

First, a quick link to a blog post (not by me) which greatly helps to clear the air on this: [The Design of Optional](https://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/design-optional/)

Optional is related to functional programming types like [Haskell Maybe](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe).  Because of the way strong typing works in functional programming, a programmer in that language would use Maybe to say that a value can be either Something, or Nothing.  The Something and Nothing are actually different types, here.  Anything that needs the values inside a Maybe *has* to handle both - the code simply won't compile if it doesn't handle both.

Compare that scenario to what is the typical situation in C-based object-oriented languages (Java, C#, C++, etc.) where an object can either have a value, or be null.  If a method needs to handle null parameters as an edge case, you need to explicitly write that code - and being the lazy programmers we all are, it's just as often we don't bother to.

Imagine what coding would be like if code wouldn't compile unless null cases were *always* explicitly handled.  That's a pretty close comparison to what happens when using Maybe in functional languages.

When we pull language features over from functional programming, and the compiler behaves the way it always has, and we code the way we always have... you can see there's a disconnect happening.

Separately, Optional can be used as a simple stand-in for null.  Because it seems familiar that way, and is new, [magpie developers](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-magpie-developer/) are prone to using it as a replacement for situations where null-checks would have happened before.  But, in the end, is foo.isPresent() really *so* different than foo != null.  If that is the sole difference, it's pointless.

And let's not even get started on how Optional can be a stand-in for autoboxing and unboxing in Java.

Now, getting back to your specific question about the particular API of Optional in Java, comparing ofNullable() vs. of(), the best I can work out is that you probably aren't expected to use those in typical code.  They are mainly used at the terminal end of [stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) operations.  You can look at the code to Optional.of() vs. Optional.ofNullable() and see for yourself that the only difference is that ofNullable checks if the value is null and arranges things for that situation.

My jaded eye doesn't see a whole lot of benefit to using Optional in Java, unless I am using Java 8 streams and I have to.  [Some](https://blog.codefx.org/techniques/intention-revealing-code-java-8-optional/) would say that the main benefit of using Optional as a type for non-stream usage is to specify that a particular parameter is optional - that is, the logic takes a different route if it's there vs. not there.  Which, again, you can simply do with null.  But I would say that the mental baggage associated with Optional means that for every forward step of supposedly more verbose code, you are taking multiple steps backwards with requiring people to understand that the Optional (in this specific case) is almost entirely cosmetic.  For the situation you described, I would probably go back to using nulls and null checks.

Comment: Thanks for your honest opinion. The biggest reason to use them (to me) is, to remind the devs, that a value could be null. Static code analysis can basically do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Angelika Langer says that `Optional.ofNullable` is only a convenience-method, calling the other both static methods from `Optional`. It is implemented as:

```
return value == null ? empty() : of(value) ;
```

Also she says that `Optional.ofNullable` was added lately to the API.

Here is her text in german language: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/80.Java8.Optional-Result/80.Java8.Optional-Result.html

So I would use `Optional.of` only when *null* is an error, which should be found early. This is what Tagir Valeev said in:
[Why use Optional.of over Optional.ofNullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696485/why-use-optional-of-over-optional-ofnullable)

Answer (score 0):

The practical answer is: on most occasions, no. As you mention, if the whole point of using Optional is not knowing if a value can return null, and you want to make it explicit in certain API, the fact that .of() can throw a null exception does not make any sense. I always use ofNullable.

The only situation I can think of is if you have a method that returns Optional (to make explicit this null-value possibility), and that method has a default/fallback value under some circumstances, you will return a "default value" Optional, using .of().

```
public Optional<String> getSomeNullableValue() {
   if (defaultSituationApplies()) { return Optional.of("default value"); }
   else {
      String value = tryToGetValueFromNetworkOrNull();
      return Optional.ofNullable(value);
   }
}
```

Then again, someone can question whether in that case you can return this default value in case of a null.

Metaphysical discussions aside, IMHO if you use Optionals, and want them to make any sense and not throw exceptions, use ofNullable().

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `Optional.of` is counterintuitive and for most use cases you would want to use `Optional.ofNullable`, but there are various purposes for `Optional.of`:

1. To explicitly throw a `NullPointerException` if the value is `null`. In this case `Optional.of` functions as a Guard.
2. When the value simply cannot be `null`. For instance, constants like `Optional.of("Hello world"!)`. This is a programming esthetics thing. `Optional.ofNullable("Hello world!")` looks weird.
3. To turn a non-null value into an `Optional` for further chaining with `map` or `filter`. This is more a programming convenience thing. Just like `Optional.stream()` exists to turn an `Optional` into a `Stream` for further chaining.

Answer (score -2):

> "What if we remove the Optional.of() method and only allow Optional.ofNullable() in Java 9, would there be any problem except backwards-compatibility?"

Yes, *of course* there will be compatibility issues. There's just too much code out there using `Optional.of`.

I agree with your general sentiment though: `Optional.of` is doing *too much* (wrapping the value **and** null-checking). For null-checks we already have `Objects.requireNonNull` which is conveniently overloaded to accept a descriptive text.

`Optional.of` and `Optional.ofNullable` should have been discarded in favor of a constructor made available for users:

```
return new Optional<>(value);
```

For null-checks this would have sufficed:

```
return new Optional<>(Objects.requireNonNull(value, "cannot be null!"));
```

Comment: I disagree. An empty optional does not by definition equate to null; it only *happens* to use null as an internal implementation detail. Guava's [`Optional`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java) has a very similar interface, but a completely different internal representation when empty. Exposing a constructor would leak implementation unnecessarily and blur the lines between null and empty.

Comment: @shmosel how will exposing a constructor leak implementation?

Comment: It implies that null is a valid value for an optional and it restricts the ability to support multiple implementations as Guava does.

Comment: @shmosel `It implies that null is a valid value for an optional` well, `Optional.ofNullable` is already doing that so the "secret" is out. "Restricting ability to support multiple implementations" has nothing to do with "leaking implementation".

Comment: No, `ofNullable()` is a factory method that *converts* null to empty. And yes, disallowing subclasses leaks information about the type hierarchy that clients have no need to know.