# Java 8 Optional. Why of and ofNullable?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a question regarding Java 8's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), the purpose of which is to tackle `NullPointerException` exceptions.

The question is, what is the reason for having both types to let us choose:

```
Optional.of(T value)     <-----non-null value, null value will throw NPE
Optional.ofNullable(T value)   <----- nullable value
```

Because what I expect is, when I use:

```
Optional.of(nullValue);
```

It won't throw a `NullPointerException`.

---

Expanded my question after some replies:

Why would people opt for Optional instead of normal `if-else` for null checking?

Comment: You may want to return a value wrapped with Optional. In this case, you can use `Optional.of(value);` .

Comment: Two out of three answers provided by people call NullPointer. How apt for this question....

Comment: Because they didn't think it through, that most normal expectation is that `of(value)` should check for null. This design choice is as absurd as the `java.util.Date` type.

Comment: Because, as others have said in answers, `Optional` is designed to reduce NPEs at the _method caller_ level, not necessarily at the _method implementation_ level. `Optional.of` is for when one _knows_ the value _is not_ `null` (and an error should be thrown if it is), `Optional.empty` is for when one _knows_ the value _is_ `null`, and `Optional.ofNullable` is for when one is _not sure_ if the value is `null` or not.

Comment: Biggest question for me is why the chose the naming that way. I would use `.of()` for nullable values and then make `ofNotNull()` for non null values, as this latter is way less used.

Comment: @Slaw In what cases would it make sense for the result of `Optional.of` to be `Optional` at all? You know it's not `null`, it's enforced to not be. Edit: You mean a method that returns either `Optional.of` or another `Optional` that actually can be empty?

Comment: @JollyJoker In cases where the logic of the (`Optional` returning) method deems the result has been found and is not, or should not be, `null`. One example would be "short-circuiting" a loop when a match is found by returning `Optional.of(matchedItem)`. If no match was found the loop would complete and the method would return `Optional.empty`. However, there are (perhaps more frequent, perhaps not) cases where even the method cannot know if the result is `null` or not and must use `Optional.ofNullable` when returning.

Comment: @Slaw Wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811956/7126740) that hopefully captures what you mean.

Comment: [Why use Optional.of over Optional.ofNullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696485/why-use-optional-of-over-optional-ofnullable) and [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) might already contain the answers you are looking for... (or follow the linked questions/answers from there on)

Comment: For example the answer(s) of [Is there a real reason to use Optional.of()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181509/is-there-a-real-reason-to-use-optional-of) might also be helpful to you

Comment: regarding your "enhanced question" (shouldn't that rather be its own one?)... within a method you could probably rather stick to `if`/`else`, but as a caller of a method, you probably rather prefer `Optional`. In the end, what does `null` even mean? not initialized? error? is not present? You would need to define that as a contract... wherease `Optional` itself describes already what the returned value will be... either present or absent...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The javadoc of [`Optional.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#of(T)) reads that explicitly :

```
@throws NullPointerException if value is null
```

and that is where the requirement of handling the cases as expected by you comes into picture with the use of `Optional.ofNullable` which is a small block of code as :

```
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? empty() : of(value); // 'Optional.of'
}
```

That said, the decision of choosing one over the other would still ***reside with the application design as if your `value` could possibly be `null` or not***.

---

On your expectation part, that was not what the `Optional` was actually intended for. The API note clarifies this further (formatting mine):

> `Optional` is primarily intended for use as a method return type where
>   there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using
>   *`null` is likely to cause error.* A variable whose type is `Optional` should never *itself be `null`*; it should always point to an `Optional` instance.

---

> purpose of Optional is to tackle NullPointerException exception.

*Aside*: Just to call it out clearly, that the choice would of course implicitly let you define if an NPE should be thrown at runtime or not. It's not determined at the compile time though.

Comment: Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null is likely to cause error. => That'll pollute the functional signature. Even Sonarqube has a warning for it. Further, returning optional just for sake of Optional has an additional penalty:
1. Optional is more costly for the GC.
2. It is suboptimal for the compiler, and does an unnecessary wrapping.

Answer (score 12):

> the purpose of Optional is to tackle `NullPointerException` exception

Yes, it is, but at usage time not at creation.

So when you receive an `Optional` from a method then you can avoid NPE by using `Optional.ifPresent`, `Optional.orElse`,`Optional.orElseGet` and `Optional.orElseThrow` methods.

But this is not the case when you're creating an Optional. Since it's your own method you have to know whether the object is nullable or not.

---

> The main point of **Optional** is to provide a means for a function returning a value to indicate the absence of a **return value**. See [this discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005952.html). This allows the caller to continue a chain of fluent method calls.
>
> Stuart Marks

Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/10584605) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's quite simple and clear with Javadoc:

**`Optional.of(T value)`** is used when you are sure that there is never a `null` value and incase null value occurs than program throws `NullPointerException` and consider as bug.

**`Optional.ofNullable(T value)`** is used when you know that there can be a `null` value and in case of it your program should behave normally.

---

[Why would people opt for Optional instead of normal if-else method for null checking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/309137)

Answer (score 7):

> Why would people opt for Optional instead of normal if-else method for null checking?

The main point of `Optional<T>` class is to provide a mean for performing *null safe* mapping operations.

`employeeOptional.map(Employee::getName).map(String::toUpperCase).ifPresent(upperCasedNameConsumer)`

The expression above can replace a cascade of `if-else` statements in a single readable expression.

`Optional.of` provides an assertion for the given argument to be a `null-null` value, otherwise, you can opt for `Optional.ofNullable` if you are not sure about the input.

I strongly recommend you to read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for `Optional<T>` class for more *optional chaining methods* that you can use for your advantage.

Answer (score 6):

After reading some answers and comments I think this explanation is missing. Consider a method like

```
public Optional<String> name(Customer c) {
    return c.isNew() ? Optional.ofNullable(getName(c)) : Optional.of(getName(c));
}
```

Here you want to throw a `NullPointerException` if the customer isn't new and is supposed to have a name; your code is inconsistent if that's ever `null`. Yet the name may not yet exist if the customer is new, hence `ofNullable` in that case and the method returns `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

- `Optional.ofNullable` is a wrapper around existing APIs that can return `null`. You would call it as a consumer of an API.
- `Optional.of/Optional.empty` is for new code written with `Optional` in mind. You would return an `Optional` created with `of/empty` as a provider of an API.

Answer (score 1):

**Code example:** `Optional.of()` VS `Optional.ofNullable()`

```
@Test
public void TestOptional() {

    String message = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println("message -> " + message + "\n");

    Optional<String> genderOptional = Optional.of(message);
    System.out.println("Optional.of(message) -> " + genderOptional);
    System.out.println("Optional.of(message).get() -> " + genderOptional.get());
    try {
        Optional.of(null);
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Optional.of(null) -> java.lang.NullPointerException \n");
    }

    System.out.println("Optional.empty() -> " + Optional.empty() + "\n");

    System.out.println("Optional.ofNullable(null) -> " + Optional.ofNullable(null));
    System.out.println("Optional.ofNullable(message) -> " + Optional.ofNullable(message));
    System.out.println("Optional.ofNullable(message).get() -> " + Optional.ofNullable(message).get());

}
```

**Output:**

```
message -> Hello World!

Optional.of(message) -> Optional[Hello World!]
Optional.of(message).get() -> Hello World!
Optional.of(null) -> java.lang.NullPointerException 

Optional.empty() -> Optional.empty

Optional.ofNullable(null) -> Optional.empty
Optional.ofNullable(message) -> Optional[Hello World!]
Optional.ofNullable(message).get() -> Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main purpose is that 
    using `Optional.of()` can throw null-pointer 
    which is exactly what we need in some cases.