# Best practice to avoid null-check conditional operator boilerplate

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

When it is not possible to use null object, what is the best practice to replace conditional operator null-checks boilerplate like this:

```
public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employee == null ? null : employee.getName();
}
```

Is there something like below in Java 8 or any utility library?

```
public String getEmployeeName() {
    return nullable(employee, employee -> employee.getName());
}

private <T, R> R nullable(T nullable, Function<T, R> doIfNotNull) {
    return nullable == null ? null : doIfNotNull.apply(nullable);
}
```

Comment: I find `return employee == null ? null : employee.getName();` to be the most readable, so perhaps it is the better solution instead of just making your code overly complex. It gets the job done, and there's nothing wrong with it - so might as well use it. That's what the conditional operator is for.

Comment: I also think this is the most clear and simple solution, please create an answer of this, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find `return employee == null ? null : employee.getName();` to be the most readable, so perhaps it is the better solution instead of just making your code overly complex. It gets the job done, and there's nothing wrong with it - so might as well use it. That's what the conditional operator is for.

Often when trying to decide which programming pattern to use, it is best to use the pattern that is the most readable and the easiest for future maintainers of your code to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You could refactor your code to this:

```
public String getEmployeeName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(employee).map(Employee::getName).orElse(null);
}
```

[`ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) creates an `Optional` value out of the given employee: if it is `null`, the empty `Optional` is returned; otherwise an `Optional` containing the employee is returned. Then, this `Optional` is mapped to the name of the employee using [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), which returns a new `Optional` with the given mapper applied if the `Optional` is non empty and an empty `Optional` if the `Optional` is empty. Finally, [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) returns the name of the employee or `null` is the `Optional` is empty.

Having said that, I don't see any added value in having this code over the `null`-check and the conditional operator: it will likely have a better performance and may also be easier to read.

Comment: This one I looking for, thanks, but I think it is more readable and simpler to just leave the conditional operator as it was originally.

Answer (score -1):

Java 8 has the new [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class, e.g.

```
private Optional<Employee> employee = Optional.empty();

public Optional<Employee> getEmployee() {
    return this.employee;
}
public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = Optional.of(employee); // null not allowed
}
public void removeEmployee() {
    this.employee = Optional.empty();
}
```

The `employee` will never be `null`, but may be "empty".

The `getEmployeeName()` method can then be implemented in two ways:

```
// Returning Optional (never null)
public Optional<String> getEmployeeName() {
    return this.employee.map(Employee::getName);
}

// Standard getter (may return null)
public String getEmployeeName() {
    return this.employee.map(Employee::getName).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats rigth. But I mean situations when you are not able to refactor the source of the null value.

Comment: The problem with `Optional` is that it can't guarantee that its input is non-null. Here's an example, http://ideone.com/8b4w6A that shows that feeding the `Optional.of` function a null value will generate a null-pointer runtime error, just like without using `Optional`.

Comment: @NateMara If the value is *allowed* to be null at that point, use [`Optional.ofNullable(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-). If value is *not* allowed to be null, then you're supposed to get the NPE.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of "Optional abuse" that Stuart Marks discusses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-java8-optional/27071576#27071576.