# Jackson. Deserialize missing properties as empty Optional<T>

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-8

Let's say I have a class like this:

```java
public static class Test {

    private Optional<String> something;

    public Optional<String> getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(Optional<String> something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
    
}
```

If I deserialize this JSON, I get an empty Optional:

```json
{"something":null}
```

But if property is missing (in this case just empty JSON), I get null instead of `Optional<T>`. I could initialize fields by myself of course, but I think it would be better to have one mechanism for `null` and missing properties. So is there a way to make jackson deserialize missing properties as empty `Optional<T>`?

Comment: Looks like convenient way to distinguish between `null` and absent value for me

Comment: Actually, I was googling exactly for a way how to differentiate cases when the field is presented in the JSON document but has `null` value, and when the field is missing. And it seems that's the only way to achieve that: empty optional - the field is here but has no value; no optional (==`null`) - the field is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional is not really meant to be used as a field but more as a return value. Why not have:

```
public static class Test {
  private String something;
  public Optional<String> getSomething() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(something);
  }
  public void setSomething(String something) {
    this.something = something;
  }
}
```

Comment: oracle does not think so   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: @AdamSkywalker depends on which source from Oracle - people who worked on the API [seem to think differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/829571).

Comment: See also [Stephen Colebourne's view](http://blog.joda.org/2015/08/java-se-8-optional-pragmatic-approach.html) (who is behind Joda time and the java time API).

Comment: Wouldn't it be overhead to create new object every time someone calls a getter?

Comment: @ArtemMalinko: You could move the Optional creation into the setter, too.

Comment: @Thilo then it will be a field:) And assylias sad that Optional is not really meant for it.

Comment: @ArtemMalinko I don't think the overhead is very material - if the few nanoseconds it takes to create and GC a short lived object is a concern in this class, you should probably not use Optional at all... You can profile your app to find the real impact,

Comment: @ArtemMalinko Do you think an `Optional` field comes without any cost?  No new object will be created for empty Optionals btw.

Comment: @zeroflagL I think this cost will be multiplied by the number of method invocations. And I don't see any reason to have this overhead although I haven't read links yet.

Comment: I've read about using Optional and you're right. It's not designed to be a field(although I don't see why it would be bad, but it's another topic). Thank you, didn't know that this simple question would give me new information about jdk8 API.

Comment: @ArtemMalinko if you have many calls, it is likely that the calling code will be optimized by the JIT. I think it will be able to remove the `Optional` instantiation in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

For a solution without getters/setters, make sure `something` get initialized like this:

```
public Optional<String> something = Optional.empty();
```

Comment: That's the only easy way to make jackson handles both null and missing values the same way