# Java 8 API static method to run Function on non-null input, or return nullValue

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Is there any Java 8 API static method that runs a `Function` on non-`null` input, but returns `nullValue` on a `null` input?

I can easily write this method myself, but I'd rather use a standard one if it exists.

```
public static <T, R> R transform(final T t, final Function<T, R> rFromT, final R nullValue) {
    return
        t == null
            ? nullValue
            : rFromT.apply(t)
    ;
}

// which can be called like:
final Number x = getNumberThatCouldBeNull();
final long   y = transform(x, Number::longValue, 0L);
```

Comment: The historical trend in Java has been to tell you that you shouldn't be dealing with null in the first place and that you should throw NullPointerExceptions as soon as possible.

Comment: The JDK has no such method. Also, what could `nullValue` possibly be apart from `null`?

Comment: @fge `nullValue` is the value that is returned if `t == null`, instead of calling `rFromT`.  See the last line of my code block, where I pass `0L` as the value for `nullValue`.

Comment: I don't think such a `transform` method would make things any clearer. `x == null ? 0L : x.longValue()` is short, clear, and perfectly fine Java 8 code.

Comment: @glts A) it prevents typo bugs, e.g., `x == null ? 0L : z.longValue()`, B) it obviates the need for the x variables, e.g. `transform(getNumberThatCouldBeNull(), Number::longValue, 0L);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no such method exists in the Java 8 API.

If anyone does find one that has been overlooked, please let everyone know.

Please see the answer from @Tunaki, and everyone else's comments, for usage of `Optional`.

In my use case, however, the method that supplies the `Object` that can be `null` is third-party, so using `Optional` doesn't offer any benefits in my case, and is less performant.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the new [Optional API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in Java 8:

```
final Number x = getNumberThatCouldBeNull();
final long   y = Optional.ofNullable(x).map(Number::longValue).orElse(0L);
```

If `x` is not null, it will be mapped to its long value and it will be returned; else `0` will be returned.

Of course, if you want to hide that inside a method, you could have the following:

```
public static <T, R> R transform(final T t, final Function<T, R> mapper, final R nullValue) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(t).map(mapper).orElse(nullValue);
}
```

Comment: Or better let getNumberThatCouldBeNull return the Optional if its in your control

Comment: I don't see the necessity of instantiating multiple `Optional`s, calling many methods that perform redundant checks, etc., just to avoid adding & using a single static method that does exactly what I want.

Comment: @XDR Like Alex has mentioned, the method `getNumberThatCouldBeNull` should probably return an `Optional` to begin with. It is actually why Optional were primarily introduced: as a return-type ([read here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23454952/1743880)). Then you really don't need that static utility, you just append calls to `map` and return a default with `orElse` or `orElseGet`.

Comment: @XDR the JDK is not-so-subtly pressuring you to stop using nulls at all.

Comment: `getNumberThatCouldBeNull` is a third-party method, in my current use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a different approach. Instead of encapsulating the null-check and function invocation in a method, you could create a [*higher-order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that would take your function and the provided default value as arguments, and would return a new function:

```
public static <T, R> Function<T, R> transform(
        Function<T, R> mapper,
        R defaultValue) {

    return t -> Optional.ofNullable(t)
            .map(mapper)
            .orElse(defaultValue);
}
```

This new function, when applied, would perform the null-check and would either return the provided default value or the value returned by the original function.

Example:

```
Function<Number, Long> transformed = transform(Number::longValue, 0L);

Number x = getNumberThatCouldBeNull();

long longNumber = transformed.apply(x);
```

The advantage of this approach is that the null-check is performed lazily.