# Method returns null and tries to call method

Tags: java, exception, null

I have a small but very annoying bug.

Actually I am programming a family tree and some cases I search for a person but sometimes the person is not in the tree (makes sense). So my methods returns null.

The problem is when I try to do something like this.

```
familytree.getNode("Peter").getName();
```

Peter is not in the tree however he tries to get the Name and my code gives me a `NullPointerException` (makes sense again).

Though I dont know how to handle this kind of problem, I have a lot similar methods like *getName()*...
For Example *getGender()*, *getWife()* etc.

I have two classes the familytree(with search, delete, etc. methods) and node (with all information about the person).

Maybe you guys have an idea!

EDIT:

For example this is my main method;

familytree.getNode("Fred").getGender(); //boolean

familytree.getNode("Max").getGender();

familytree.getNode("Peter").getGender();

familytree.getNode("Fe").getPartner(); //Partner Name

familytree.getNode("Freddyy").getName(); //String

How do I check for every case if its a nullpointer?

Comment: Is `Node` a framework class or your own code? if the latter the best way was to return a dummy element instead of a `null`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Well, "dummy" elements make sense sometimes; but here, it is hard. Defining "correct" semantics for an "empty" dummy person looks hard. I don't think that this is the natural, first solution here.

Comment: @GhostCat I'd say it is the perfect example of a useful Dummy element. The OP has lots of code througout the program that wants to access the getters on the elements. The only reason for the null-check is to display some replacement text which could also be taken from the dummy.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Then please explain the semantics of a "Dummy" person to me. How old is a dummy person? What is its name? How do you sort an array with 3 real and 7 dummy persons? On and on it goes. You are just moving the **real* issue into many different places now. All of a sudden, you have 50 methods that need special handling for dummy persons.

Comment: @GhostCat *"Then please explain the semantics of a "Dummy" person to me. How old is a dummy person? What is its name?"* if you'd get a `null`, what would you print out as name/age? what is the exact reason not to get those "null replacements" from the dummy?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle If you get a null, you either throw an exception; or you put the code there that deals with it. That is the whole point: if the logic allows for empty results, then it has to be able to deal with that fact. That empty default person you suggest just *obscures* the real problem: the fact that he thinks he can get away without thinking about that "error case" when the person is actually not in his tree.

Comment: @GhostCat *"get away without thinking about that "error case""* that's the point: **is it** an *error case* as far as the logic is concerned? From what the OP wrote in her question I can't see this.

Comment: Probably *error case* is the wrong word. But even then: he simply didn't design his interfaces to support this case. Introducing a dummy person to avoid NPEs will not fix his broken design. He has to step back and find a working end to end solution. Taking his comments so far, he simply does not **understand** what is wrong. That empty dummy person idea will thus not help him.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java 8,instead of checking for null,try using the 
Optional

Maybe this topic can help you : [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional)

At first using Optional may seem like more code,but in the end it's a lot cleaner and more effective.

Comment: You are for sure right; but this guy has problems understanding that returning null requires to check for null. Not sure if Optionals will really work out for him.

Comment: No its not a problem to check ifs zero, the problem is how I avoid that null (objects) try to call some methods...

Comment: @Nado You have been told **repeatedly** what to do. The thing is: your idea how to **implement** your application is simply **broken**. There is **no** point in you insisting "but I want to do it *this* way" ... because *this* your way **does not work**. Please accept reality, **read** the advise you asked us for ... and go with that.

Comment: Ok then please my edition in the question, and show me to handle this problem.

Comment: @Nado: how often do we have to tell you that you **can not** keep your code as is? Your approach is **broken** and insisting "but i want to keep it that way" wastes your time ... and ours. The code you added *can* throw those NullPointerExceptions all over the place. You **must** rework your design to somehow deal with the fact that your lookups either return null, or an Optional that is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Simple idea: don't do that!

If your method *can* return **null**, then you have to **check** for that, like:

```
Person p = familytree.getNode("Peter");
if (p != null) {
 do something with p.getName();
} else {
 tell user: Peter is not known!
```

Or, check upfront:

```
if (familytree.contains("Peter")) {
  p = familytree.getNode("Peter"); // will be save
```

Comment: Yeah but then I would have to check everything when I try to get the Name

Comment: Of course. Probably 25% of your life as Java programmer is to check for null values. If you design an interface that **allows** for returning null, then yes, you have to check **each and any** usage of that interface. The alternative is to come up with methods that never return null. Which is pretty hard for such kind of map/lookup code.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
Node node = familytree.getNode("Peter");
if ( null == node ){

    return "non existant";
}

String name = node.getName();
```

Comment: Yeah that would makes sense, but I have several methods, returns with boolens, nodes, strings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: actually, you can return a default Node instead of null at FamilyTree#getNode when the node is not found, that should be the proper way to do it.

---

Or you can use Java8 Optional and decide at every call what to do if getNode was null:

The key is to modify the FamilyTree#getNode method using Optional.ofNullable
and then use map and orElse to deal with possible null values, providing a default value or getting the actual property.

See this :

```
static class FamilyTree {
    private Map<String, Node> nodes = new HashMap<>();
    // put some values in this map

    Optional<Node> getNode(String key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.nodes.get(key));
    }
}

static class Node {
    private boolean gender;
    private String partner;
    private String name;

    boolean getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    String getPartner() {
        return this.partner;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

@Test
public void test_nado() {
    FamilyTree familytree = new FamilyTree();

    familytree.getNode("Fred").map(Node::getGender).orElse(false); //boolean
    familytree.getNode("Max").map(Node::getGender).orElse(false);
    familytree.getNode("Peter").map(Node::getGender).orElse(false);
    familytree.getNode("Fe").map(Node::getPartner).orElse(""); //Partner Name
    familytree.getNode("Freddyy").map(Node::getName).orElse(""); //String
}
```

Comment: map tells the optional what to do with its value if it is not null (here use a getter), and to do nothing if it is null. orElse provides a default value if the optional value was null.

Comment: As mentioned before: I fail to see how this really helps. Imagine  you asking your coworker: "could you please look up X in the phone book and tell me his number?" And your coworker comes back and says "it is 000-000-000" because actually X is not in the phone book, and those zeros are the "empty person" default phone number --- do you think those numbers help you? Wouldnt it be better if you were told "X is not in the phone book" instead. Now **you** have to figure "oh, 000.... means that X is unknown".