# Optional.ofNullable(i).ifPresent... vs if (i != null)

Tags: java, option-type

I've recently seen a [blog post](https://struberg.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/optional-vs-if-null/) ([tweeted by @java](https://twitter.com/java/status/832215206117810176)) that suggests the following code is becoming increasingly common:

```
Optional.ofNullable(i).ifPresent(x -> doBlah(x));
```

instead of:

```
if (i != null) {
  doBlah(i);
}
```

The use of Optional in this case appears very awkward to me, even ignoring the naming of the variables - the latter is easier to read and more idiomatic for the use case (handling nulls). I believe this also captures semantics better - i is likely from code that doesn't adhere to the semantics that Optional is trying to capture (as described in the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) and in [this Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)).

I do not see one, but is there a good semantic cause to prefer the Optional.isNullable approach (ignoring the performance impact it may have depending on how it is used)?

Comment: `orElse(x->doBla(x))` is incorrect, unless `i` happens to be a lambda.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/152/optional

Comment: Yeah, for the case you cited I'd just stick with a good old `if` statement. But you can do some [neat tricks with filtering and mapping optionals](http://codingjunkie.net/working-with-java8-optionals/)

Comment: Those two pieces of code you gave are logically different. The first looks like it is trying to call `doBla` if `i` is null (though it doesn't look right to me). The second calls `doBla` if `i` is not null.

Comment: It should say `ifPresent`, not `orElse`. Otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I blindly copied the source; I'll update with correct examples and reword slightly to better capture my query.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, I think this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is an opinion-based question.

Comment: IMO: Optional **should not** be used this way. If it's becoming more common, well, if all your friends jump off a bridge...

Comment: @JoeC I don't think the question is opinion-based because the example given is not how Optionals were actually intended to be used.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense for the same unit of code to wrap a potentially null object in an Optional only to call `ifPresent()` on it.

The more useful case is for an API that can return null objects to instead return an Optional. This forces the caller to handle potential null results in a null-safe way. Since the API and the caller are separate units of code, the extra work of wrapping an object in an Optional and forcing the caller to invoke `ifPresent()` is not just busy-work but actually enforces a safer contract that protects against null-pointer exceptions.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is the way `Optional` was designed to be used: as a return value.