# java method return multiple values

Tags: java, methods, return

I have a method that I wish to call twice in a program. When I call it first, I do not want it to return any value, but when I call it in a different class, I want it to return a string `output`.

It seems like rather a waste to copy and paste and entire method to add just one return line the for this second instance.

I considered adding a parameter `location` and then saying:

```
if (location.equals("location1")) {
    return null;
}
else {
    return output;
}
```

But I really do not want to return anything, even `null`, the first time I reference this method.

Is this possible?

Comment: if your method return String then use return " ";

Comment: "When I call it first, I do not want it to return any value" You always have to return a value, if the method is non-null (if you don't throw something, that is). Why not just ignore the return value?

Comment: I can easily do so. I was simply curious if it was possible...

Comment: "non-null" I meant non-void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **use `Optional` (from Java8)** exactly for this purpose as shown below:

```
public Optional<String> myMethod(String location) {
   if (location.equals("location1")) {
     return Optional.empty();//returns empty Optional object
   } else {
     return Optional.of(output);//returns String wrapped by Optional
   }
}
```

I suggest you look at the `java.util.Optional` API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) & below text (emphasis mine).

> **java.util.Optional container object which may or may not contain a non-null value**. If a
>   value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return
>   the value.

Comment: Fantastic! This is essentially what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of the `Optional` class, but for the use case described it is too much effort. If one wants to wrap the return value inside an object, this can be done in many other ways. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your method has `String` as its return type, it must always return a `String` (or null, or throw an exception). From [JLS Sec 8.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7):

> If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

"Complete normally" is a slightly funny phrase if you are unfamiliar with it. Returning a value is not completing normally, believe it or not. From [JLS Sec 14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1):

> If all the steps are carried out as described, with no indication of abrupt completion, the statement is said to complete normally. However, certain events may prevent a statement from completing normally:
>
> - The break (§14.15), continue (§14.16), and return (§14.17) statements cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements that contain them.
> - Evaluation of certain expressions may throw exceptions from the Java Virtual Machine (§15.6). An explicit throw (§14.18) statement also results in an exception. An exception causes a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements.

Since you're not in a loop, you can't use `break` or `continue`; so, you always have to return a value or throw to avoid normal completion.

The easiest thing to do is just not to do anything with the return value where you call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just ignore the return value in first "location"? Or if method needs to know the context just pass a parameter to it and ignore the return value in first location? Like that:

```
public String myMethod(boolean calledFromFirstLocation) {
    if (calledFromFirstLocation) {
        // do something specific for 1st location
        return null; // ignore it later
    } else {
        return "output";
    }
}
```

Then just call it like:

```
// return value ignored, method knows it is being called from location1
myMethod(true);
// should print "output"
System.out.println(myMethod(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Java` is a strongly typed language. All methods have a return type (including `void`, which means `return nothing`).

It is not possible to have method returning nothing if its type is not `void` and that cannot be changed. This is for a good reason, too: methods that return values are typically used for populating parameters of certain data types.

For example, consider the method

```
public abstract int calculate();
```

which is called by an application, for calculating a value, which is saved in a parameter for subsequent use, e.g.

```
int result = calculate();
```

What would go into `result`, if there was an option to "not return anything" from the `calculate()` method?

For this and numerous other reasons, a method must always return a value of a specific data type, or be of type `void` and this is enforced by the `Java` compiler. If it does return a value, it can be used or ignored, according to the needs of the calling application.

The use of the [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class, introduced in `Java 8` and suggested in another answer, is probably not the most suitable approach for use cases like the question above. Having said that, a nice discussion about `Optional` can be found in [another StackOverlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional).