# Java 8 : Cannot invoke orElseThrow() on the primitive type void

Tags: java, java-8

I was trying the following code:

```
Optional.ofNullable(listEvidence).ifPresent(
            eviList -> {
                List<String> repoKeysList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (Evidence evidence : eviList) {
                    repoKeysList.add(evidence.getRepositoryKey());
                }   
                log.debug("UserContentBean: processRepoSyncCleanup repoKeysList - "+repoKeysList);
                evidenceDetailDAO.updateIsSelectedFlag(repoKeysList, 0,configurationService.getNodeName());
            }
            ).orElseThrow();
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke orElseThrow() on the primitive type void
```

It seems to me that `orElseThrow()` is misplaced in the code. but `updateIsSelectedFlag()` throws an exception which needs to be handled.

Also, this piece of code is a part of, say, `method1()`. I tried adding throws Exception to `method1()`, but it yet asks me to handle the exception raised by `updateIsSelectedFlag()`. I couldn't understand the reason for the same.

Comment: This code has a smell about it.  You're using `Optional.ifPresent`, but you're *building the `Optional` in situ*.  It seems to me like you should just be using normal `if` statements here.

Comment: Yurk... Instead of doing that, simply do `Objects.requireNonNull(listEvidence, "listEvidence");` and use directly the `listEvidence` without `Optional`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the `Optional` class.

First problem is that inside `ifPresent()` you are using a lambda expression that contains code that throws a checked exception. Lambdas cannot throw checked excpetions (i.e those that do not extend `RuntimeException`).

Second problem is that you are misusing the `orElseThrow()` method of `Optional`. It is supposed to be used to either get a *maybe nullable* object or throw an exception if it is actually null like so:

```
MyObject notNull = Optional.ofNullable(maybeNull).orElseThrow(new MyException());
```

For your use case you can either go with the old school if-else or if you want to play with `Optional` for some reason the way to go about it would be:

```
Optional.ofNullable(listEvidence).ifPresent((eviList -> {
  // your logic
  try {
    evidenceDetailDAO.updateIsSelectedFlag(repoKeysList, 0,configurationService.getNodeName());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
});
```

This way you convert the checked exception into an unchecked one inside the lambda and you can handle it outside the Optional by adding another `try-catch` for `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a poor approach to the situation.  In general, speaking on the use of `Optional`, you're expecting that usually as a *return* value, not a value that you do operations on.  In effect, you're still doing a `null` check; it's just unnecessarily obfuscated.

Instead, perform the operations you intend to do with the `if` statement.

```
if (null != listEvidence) {
    List<String> repoKeysList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Evidence evidence : listEvidence) {
        repoKeysList.add(evidence.getRepositoryKey());
    }
    log.debug("UserContentBean: processRepoSyncCleanup repoKeysList - " + repoKeysList);
    evidenceDetailDAO.updateIsSelectedFlag(repoKeysList, 0, configurationService.getNodeName());
}
```

For more context into the conversation around `Optional`, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) goes into some detail as to what use cases `Optional` is meant for.

Comment: @JeremyGrand:  Looks to me like the original code is content with throwing the exception.  I see no reason not to replicate that here.

Comment: oh yeah, I just went crazy for a bit, their issue was that the Consumer did not allow for a checked exception to be thrown. The if statement fixes that.

Answer (score 3):

`Optional.ifPresent` returns a `void` type, and not the `Optional` itself.

What you're trying to do should be done with a  `if {listEvidence != null} else {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7573818/jeremy-grand), `Optional.ifPresent` returns `void`. In addition, you miss an argument to `public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X`

Note that `orElseThrow` will never handle the exception thrown by `updateIsSelectedFlag()`. The purpose of `orElseThrow` is to "get the value inside the optional if it present and if its is not present throw an exception".

`updateIsSelectedFlag()` must throw unchecked exceptions if you want to use it in the `Consumer<T>` that is the argument of `ifPresent`. Have a look at the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface, it does not support checked exceptions. If `updateIsSelectedFlag()` cannot throw unchecked exceptions, you have to catch the exceptions and throw a new unchecked exception (such as a `RuntimeException`) in the `Consumer`.

You could achieve something similar to what you wrote by using `Optional.map` instead of `Optional.ifPResent` and by fixing the rest of the code (managing your exception, adding the argument to `orElseThrow`). But as suggested by many, you should better rewrite the code. For now, you are not writing what you intend to do.

Tip : since you have the good idea of using `Optional`, avoid to test for a `null` value. Prefer
`listEvidence = Optional.ofNullable(something);`
`if (listEvidence.isPresent())`
to
`if (null != listEvidence)`
If you avoid `null` values, your code will never throw `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody else has said, in your case it's better just to use `if (listEvidence != null)`.

**However**, if you do need to use an optional like this in another case, you can store it in a variable instead of chaining everything together.

Say `listEvidence` is of type `MyClass`.

```
Optional<MyClass> myOptional = Optional.ofNullable(listEvidence);

myOptional.ifPresent(
        eviList -> {
            List<String> repoKeysList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Evidence evidence : eviList) {
                repoKeysList.add(evidence.getRepositoryKey());
            }   
            log.debug("UserContentBean: processRepoSyncCleanup repoKeysList - "+repoKeysList);
            evidenceDetailDAO.updateIsSelectedFlag(repoKeysList, 0,configurationService.getNodeName());
        });

myOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
```