# java 8 optional to replace return null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am refactoring the code to Java 8 and I want to replace null checks with Optional.

```
public Employee findEmployeeById(String id) {
    List<Employee> empList = .. //some db query
    return (empList.isEmpty() ? null : empList.get(0));
}
```

`Optional.ofNullable(empList.get(0))` won't work as when it will throw `IndexOutofBoundException`

Or should I ideally replace null with `Optional.empty()`?

Comment: Why doesn't your query only return a single result in the first place?

Comment: That is a complex logic ....of left joins and all....I understand you point but cant really change that

Comment: `return empList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(empList.get(0));`

Comment: When I replace this code and inspect Optiona.empty() ,it shows null then what is the use to use Optional

Comment: Optional wraps a reference to an object, or nothing. Of course, inside the Optional, it it wraps nothing, the reference to the object is null. What else could it be? What matters is that what your method returns is an Optional, which is never null, and which forced the caller to think about and deal with an empty value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Jesper already mentioned in the comments, you have to check whether the list is empty and then return an empty `Optional`.

```
public Optional<Employee> findEmployeeById(String id) {
    List<Employee> empList = .. //some db query
    return empList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(empList.get(0));
}
```

An `Optional` is a wrapper around a potentially `null` value that allows you to avoid explicitly checking for `null` when you use it.

Have a look at the [Optional documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to see what functionality it provides.

For example you can get an employee's name or "unknown" if it's absent, without checking for `null`:

```
Optional<Employee> emp = findEmployeeById(id);
String name = emp.map(Employee::getName).orElse("unknown");
```

You may read [this post about Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) to see if it makes sense for you to use `Optional`.

Comment: Isn't it bad to return Optional.of instead of Optional.ofNullable as a practice?

Comment: @BilboBaggins if the value can be null, then yes, you have to use `Optional.ofNullable()`.

Answer (score 6):

To me the natural solution would be to keep your `? :` construct as in [Floern’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43952676/5772882). If, however, you want to get rid of that, there is also an elegant solution without it:

```
public Optional<Employee> findEmployeeById(String id) {
    List<Employee> empList = .. //some db query
    return empList.stream().findFirst();
}
```

This gives you what you want because `findFirst()` returns an `Optional`. If you don’t care which element you get — or you know there’s never more than one — you may alternatively use `findAny()`, it too returns an `Optional`.

Comment: Good one, didn't think about that

Comment: Nice! You don't even need the `empList` local, so this can be reduced to `return someDbQuery().stream().findFirst()`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply replace your method with:

```
public Optional<Employee> findEmployeeById(String id) {
    List<Employee> empList = .. //some db query
    return (empList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : 
              Optional.ofNullable(empList.get(0)));
}
```

I suggest you wrap the `empList.get(0)` in a `Optional.ofNullable` in case it *might still be null*.

As far as *why* that is better: think about the caller of the method. Whomever is now calling your method *has to think* what to actually do when the result is `empty`.

Besides you are now **forced** into writing code like:

```
Optional<Employee> emp = findEmployeeById("12");

if (emp.isPresent()) {

} else {
    ....
}
```

You can also chain this to become more fluent like:

```
emp.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)
```

Or other Optional methods.

That is simply not the case *when you return an Employee*. You are not even thinking (usually) to check if the reference is null.

That makes your code less error-prone and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to do it as follows:

```
return Optional.of(empList).filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).map(list -> list.get(0));
```

This will automatically return an empty `Optional` in case the list is empty or `empList.get(0)` returns `null`.

If `empList` can be `null`, consider using `Optional.ofNullable(empList)` instead of `Optional(empList)`.