# What should I return instead of null?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I've heard that it is bad practice to return `null`.

What are the alternatives to returning `null` in this case?

```
    public RollingStock getHeadPoint() {
        if (!train.isEmpty()) {
            return train.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could `throw new RuntimeException("No train available")` or similar...

Comment: You could change the return type to `Optional<RollingStock>`

Comment: You could also ```throw new IllegalStateException("Train is empty")``` or follow the Java Spec guidelines where they throw ```NoSuchElementException``` e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeFirst()

Comment: @deHaar: Unchecked exception? That might not be the nicest thing to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java 8 optional to replace return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951727/java-8-optional-to-replace-return-null)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels right, definitley not the nicest...

Comment: @rhowell That's a very old topic and I think it's outdated, at least for `Java 8+`. Using `Optional` avoids NPEs and many different sorts of confusion. One may understand by a method's return type whether it is required or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the best option is to return an `Optional<RollingStock>`, like the foillowing:

```
public Optional<RollingStock> getHeadPoint() {
    if (!train.isEmpty()) {
        // or even Optional.ofNullable, if you are not sure 
        // whether train.get(0) is null or not 
        return Optional.of(train.get(0));  
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

---

Assuming `train` is a collection, as an alternative to manual wrapping the value into an `Optional` you could use `Stream API`:

```
public Optional<RollingStock> getHeadPoint() {
    return train.stream()
                .findFirst();
}
```

In some cases using inline `train.stream().findFirst()` may be more preferable than wrapping it into a separate method.

---

Once you already modified your method `getHeadPoint` to return `Optional<RollingStock>` you can use it as follows:

```
// ...
RollingStock headPoint = getHeadPoint().orElse(yourDefaultRollingStock);
// or
RollingStock headPoint = getHeadPoint().orElseGet(aMethodGettingYourDefaultRollingStock());
// or
RollingStock headPoint = getHeadPoint().orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("The train is empty!"));
// or
getHeadPoint().ifPresent(headPoint -> doSomethingWithHeadPoint(headPoint));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate "`get`" and "`search/find`" methods :

- `getHeadPoint` : some train should exist. If not, it's against your business, throw an exception
- `findHeadPoint` : non-existence of the train is coherent to your business, return null

Answer (score 0):

You could define a TrainIsEmptyException and throw that when the train is empty. Make it a checked Exception. Or you can just return null.