# How to use Java 8 Optional with Moxy and Jersey

Tags: java-8, jersey, moxy

Is it possible to use Jersey with Moxy to/from Json and Java 8 Optionals?

How to configure it?

Comment: AFAIK you need a custom adapter to handle that.

Comment: No drop-in jar as maven dependency? I'm pretty sure I'm not the first with this issue.

Comment: I'd also like to ask how to write an XmlAdapter for an Optional which is generic.... in case this is part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare following class:

```
public class OptionalAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    public Optional<T> unmarshal(T value) throws Exception {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value);
    }

    @Override
    public T marshal(Optional<T> value) throws Exception {
        return value.orElse(null);
    }

}
```

And use like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SampleRequest {

    @XmlElement(type = Integer.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = OptionalAdapter.class)
    private Optional<Integer> id;

    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = OptionalAdapter.class)
    private Optional<String> text;

    /* ... */

}
```

Or declare in `package-info.java` and remove `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` from POJOs:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = Optional.class, value = OptionalAdapter.class)
})
```

But here are some drawbacks:

1. Adapter above can only work with simple types like Integer, String, etc. that can be parsed by MOXY by default.
2. You have to specify `@XmlElement(type = Integer.class)` explicitly to tell the parser type are working with, otherwise `null` values would be passed to adapter's `unmarshal` method.
3. You miss the opportunity of using adapters for custom types, e.g. custom adapter for `java.util.Date` class based on some date format string. To overcome this you'll need to create adapter something like `class OptionalDateAdapter<String> extends XmlAdapter<String, Optional<Date>>`.

Also using `Optional` on field is not recommended, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23454952) for details.

Taking into account all the above, I would suggest just using `Optional` as return type for your POJOs:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SampleRequest {

    @XmlElement
    private Integer id;

    public Optional<Integer> getId() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(id);
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```