# How to use Optional in Java8

Tags: java-8, option-type

A little confused about the usage of Optional.
How to get the same result with Optional?

```
ModuleEntity module = n.getOutline().getModule()==null?n.getOutline().getParent().getModule():n.getOutline().getModule();
return m.getModule().equals(module)
```

tried a lot, but always `NullpointerException...`

**eg**:

```
m.getModule().equals(Optional.ofNullable(n.getOutline().getModule()).orElse(n.getOutline().getParent().getModule())))
```

Here is the complete code:

```
List<RoleModel> roles = app.getRoles().stream()
            .filter(r -> RoleType.MODULE.equals(r.getType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
            .map(m -> {
                        RoleModel role = Entity2ModelUtils.entity2Model(m);
                        role.setRoles(app.getRoles().stream()
                                    .filter(o -> RoleType.OUTLINE.equals(o.getType()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                                        .filter(n -> m.getModule().equals(Optional.ofNullable(n.getOutline().getModule()).map(zz->n.getOutline().getModule()).orElse(n.getOutline().getParent().getModule())))
                                        .map(z -> Entity2ModelUtils.entity2Model(z))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                        return role;})
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what is n ? show that class

Comment: Another Object..Added complet code

Comment: it is better if you tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @pvpkiran  `reuturn a==null?b:c` That's what am trying to do .

Comment: Using `Optional` just to replace a ternary statement is a dubious practice, but `a==null ? b : a` can be written as `Optional.ofNullable(a).orElse(b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, do not use `Optional` just to replace a ternary statement. See question [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) for more information.

Though if you really want to use an `Optional` in your case, you could do:

```
Optional
  .ofNullable(n.getOutline().getModule())
  .orElseGet(() -> n.getOutline().getParent().getModule());
```

The key here is the lazy evaluation of the else statement. I guess when you were using `Optional.ofNullable(...).orElse(...)`, it was the content of the `orElse` that were always executed that throw the nullpointer exception.