# Java 8 Optional - how to handle nested Object structures

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Is there any simple way to reduce the lines of code to print the innermost not `null` object using `Optional` as alternative to the below code. I feels like we have to write more lines of code to avoid the null checks now.

Is there any easy way to make this code short and sweet in Java 8?

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalInnerStruct {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creepy initialization step, dont worry
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setHuman(Optional.empty());

    // with optional
    Optional<Human> optionalHuman = employee.getHuman();
    if (optionalHuman.isPresent()) {
        Human human = optionalHuman.get();
        Optional<Male> optionalMale = human.getMale();
        if (optionalMale.isPresent()) {
            Male male = optionalMale.get();
            Optional<Integer> optionalAge = male.getAge();
            if (optionalAge.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println("I discovered the variable finally " + optionalAge.get());
            }

        }

    }

    // without optional in picture, it will be something like:
    /*if(null! = employee.getHuman() && null!= employee.getHuman().getMale() && null! = employee.getHuman().getMale().getAge()) {
        System.out.println("So easy to find variable " + employee.getHuman().getMale().getAge());
    }*/
}

static class Employee {

    Optional<Human> human;

    public Optional<Human> getHuman() {
        return human;
    }

    public void setHuman(Optional<Human> human) {
        this.human = human;
    }
}

class Human {
    Optional<Male> male;

    public Optional<Male> getMale() {
        return male;
    }

    public void setMale(Optional<Male> male) {
        this.male = male;
    }
}

class Male {
    Optional<Integer> age;

    public Optional<Integer> getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Optional<Integer> age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: don't use `Optional` as a field type, getters shouldn't return `Optional` as well

Comment: hi @Andrew, can you please explain your comment

Comment: here is a good thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional

Comment: here is a good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) here

```
employee.getHuman()
        .flatMap(Human::getMale)
        .flatMap(Male::getAge)
        .ifPresent(age -> System.out.println("I discovered the variable finally " + age);
```

Comment: While using map API, we need to add an extra call to retrieve the value before using the transformed value. This way, the Optional wrapper will be removed. This operation is performed implicitly when using flatMap, from http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional , will be helpful for someone like me in future.