# Difference between if(object == null) v if(null == object)?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the two? Which one is better? I was asked this in an Interview.

The only difference I can think of is that if you wanted to do `if(null == object)` and forgot to add `==` and added `=`, it will not have any side-effect to your program. But if you do this mistake while doing `if(object = null)` then your program is toast.

Comment: Some coders prefer "yoda" checks `null == value` where others prefer "natural language" form `value == null` - it's personal preference, in Java at least. I'd say your conclusion is also not bad

Comment: Oh, they really find one of the two better. You should ask them, which is better: `if(a==b)` or `if(b==a)`.

Comment: Unless you are assigning to a Boolean `if (o = null)` is a compile time error, and if it is a Boolean it is an NPE, so I think the correct answer is that `null = o` is an outdated Cism.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Nayuki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226460/441662), if the programmer mistypes = for ==, like if (object = null), there are still few cases where compilation error won't come and bugs would creep in the code.

For example: `if (boolean1 = boolean2)`, is an assignment expression first and then is evaluated for the if condition. Another problematic code is `if (wrapperBool = null)`, where wrapperBool is a Boolean wrapper class variable. It will throw a NullPointerException (NPE) at runtime.

But as [Benny mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226516/441662), mistyping should be caught upfront with unit test case(s).

Answer (score 0):

In the Java programming language, the two expressions `if (object == null)` versus `if (null == object)` do exactly the same thing, because the `==` operator is commutative. The former notation is considered more natural when spoken in English, whereas the latter notation has some proponents.

If the programmer mistypes `=` for `==`, like `if (object = null)`, this is a compile-time error in Java because the condition expression must be a `boolean` value, not `Object`. Hence, `if (object == null)` and `if (null == object)` are equally secure against typos **in Java**.

But in C and C++, integer, floating-point, and pointer types are implicitly coerced to `bool` in a condition expression. Writing `if (object = null)` will compile but do the wrong thing, whereas writing `if (null = object)` should trigger a compile-time error.

See also: https://coderanch.com/t/489740/java/difference-null-object-object-null

Comment: The post you link gives a wrong explanation: == is not associative, but commutative as you yourself state.

Answer (score 0):

Because of its [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), the only difference between `object == null` and `null == object` (the [Yoda version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)) is of **cognitive nature**: how the code is read and digested by the reader. I don't know the definitive answer though, but I do know I personally prefer *comparing the object I'm inspecting to something else, rather than comparing something else to the object I'm inspecting*, if that makes any sense. Start with the subject, then the value to compare it to.

In some other languages this comparison style is more useful.

To safe guard against a missing "=" sign in general though, I think writing `null == object` is a misguided act of [defensive programming](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/defensive-programming-being-just-enough.html). The better way around this particular code is by guaranteeing the behavior with a junit test. Remember, the possible mistake of missing an "=" is not dependant on the method's input arguments - you are not dependent on the right use of this API by other people - so a junit test is perfect to safe guard against that instead. Anyway you will want to write junit tests to verify the behavior; a missing "=" naturally falls within scope.

Or maybe, could it have been a trick question to get you on the topic of discussing the [uses of Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/441662) to avoid raw null-checks altogether?