# Java 10 ifPresentOrElse that return boolean

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, java-10

I am a little confused on "how to do this properly":

```
 // return true: if present and number of lines != 0
  boolean isValid(Optional<File> optFile) {
    return optFile.ifPresentOrElse(f -> return !isZeroLine(f), return false);
 }

 private boolean isZeroLine(File f)  {
    return MyFileUtils.getNbLinesByFile(f) == 0;
 }
```

I know the syntax is not correct and not compiling, but it's just for you to get the idea.

How can I turn this into 'clean code'?
i.e. avoid doing:

```
if (optFile.isPresent()) {//} else {//}
```

Comment: kind of `optFile.map(this::isZeroLine).orElse(false)` ? but not sure if having an optional as argument is a good idea

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That's it !

Comment: It is becoming impossible to read Java..

Comment: @Tyvain Both [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617309/java-10-ifpresentorelse-that-return-boolean#comment92168796_52617309) and [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618642/2525313) are good solutions. Re having an `Optional` parameter, don't succumb to the [majority opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/2525313) ([minority report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071576/2525313)).  If you already have an `Optional<File>`, there is no need to unpack it to avoid the `Optional` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dealing with boolean return type(easily inferred `Predicate`s), one way to do that could be to use [`Optional.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) :

```
boolean isValid(Optional<File> optFile) {
    return optFile.filter(this::isZeroLine).isPresent();
}
```

But, then using `Optional`s arguments seems to be a poor practice. As suggested in comments by Carlos as well, another way of implementing it could possibly be:

```
boolean isValid(File optFile) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(optFile).map(this::isZeroLine).orElse(false);
}
```

---

On another note, `ifPresentOrElse` is a construct to be used while performing some actions corresponding to the presence of the `Optional` value something like :

```
optFile.ifPresentOrElse(this::doWork, this::doNothing)
```

where the corresponding actions could be -

```
private void doWork(File f){
     // do some work with the file
}

private void doNothing() {
     // do some other actions
}
```