# Optional and casting at the same time

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, bigdecimal

I have a `BigDecimal` amount that I want to cast to `Long` if it is not `null`, but I got a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception doing:

```
BigDecimal bgAmount = getAmount();

long totalSupplyFilterMin = 
              Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount.longValue()).orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: Perhaps it is null?

Comment: Why use optional here? It would be much better and idiomatic to use a ternary operator `long x = bgAmount == null ? Long.MIN_VALUE : bgAmount.longValue()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't...use an `Optional` for what is a null check.  Just expressly check for `null` and *then* dereference the object if it isn't null.

```
BigDecimal bgAmount = getAmount();
long totalSupplyFilterMin = Long.MIN_VALUE;
if(bgAmount != null) {
    totalSupplyFilterMin = bgAmount.longValue();
}
```

[You use `Optional` as a **return** value to indicate the absence of a value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/1079354)  It is *not* a replacement for a null check.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you use `Optional` incorrectly. When `bgAmount == null`, then `Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount.longValue())` throws `NPE`. Correct usages are:

```
Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount)
        .orElse(BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE))
        .longValue();
```

or

```
Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount)
                   .map(BigDecimal::longValue)
                   .orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems `bgAmount` is null so upon invoking `bgAmount.longValue()` the exception arises.

```
long totalSupplyFilterMin = Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount.longValue())
                                    .orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

btw don't use `ofNullable` here as `bgAmount.longValue()` will never be null.

you probably wanted to do:

```
Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount).map(s -> s.longValue()).orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `bgAmount` is `null`, calling `longValue` on it will result in a `NullPointerException`. Note this has nothing to do with the optional, as this is called before you even apply the optional.

Instead, you can call `map` to safely apply this conversion:

```
long totalSupplyFilterMin = 
     Optional.ofNullable(bgAmount).map(BigDecimal::longValue).orElse(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally we have a pattern for this in our code base, something like the code below, but it's not much different that [Makoto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694896/1059372) in this case:

```
long totalSupplyFilterMin = Long.MIN_VALUE;
BigDecimal bgAmount;
if ((bgAmount = getAmount()) != null) {
     totalSupplyFilterMin = bgAmount.longValue();
}
```

The only difference in the number of times you *read* variable `bgAmount`, this code reads it once, as opposed of twice in the above answer (this is extremely rarely important, if ever - but I've build a habit writing code like this).