# Replacing null check with java 8 optional

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I am trying to replace below code block with optional, just want to check will there be any bad implications of doing this like performance or anything as such?

Existing code:

```
UserObj userObj=new UserObj();
Object result = fetchDetails();
if (null != result) {
    userObj.setResult(result.toString());
}
```

With Java 8 `Optional`:

```
UserObj userObj=new UserObj();
Optional.ofNullable(fetchDetails()).ifPresent(var -> userObj.setResult(var.toString()));
```

Doing this change just to make code look concise as there are lot of null check blocks in my code.

Comment: The correct way would be if `fetchDetails` would already return an `Optional`. This class is meant to be returned by methods that want to indicate *no result*. Otherwise the additional safety-mechanism doesn't catch (to prevent people from forgetting the null-check, they can not forget if they only get an `Optional` back. Because they can not access the content without triggering the check).

Comment: I think this question should be asked in `Code Review` community.

Comment: Your old code looks dubious: `userObj.setResult(userObj.toString())`. Apparently, you actually wanted `userObj.setResult(result.toString())`

Comment: There is a slight overhead of using `Optional`, you and your users will probably never notice. Your code using `Optional` looks good. I agree with those saying that it will be even better if `fetchDetails` would return an `Optional` from the start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `Optional`. It is not just for replacing

```
if(obj != null){ ... }
```

The main point of `Optional` is to provide a means for a function returning a value to indicate the absence of a return value. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124853/10584605) for more details.

The proper use of `Optional` in your case would be returning optional `ResultObj` from `fetchDetails` method:

```
Optional<ResultObj> fetchDetails() {
   ...
}
```

Then you simply chain the methods on fetched `Optional` as you did before.

**Update**

In case you cannot modify `fetchDetails` there is still an option of wrapping it into your own method like the following:

```
Optional<ResultObj> fetchOptionalDetails() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(fetchDefails());
}
```

Creating a new method will add a tiny overhead, but the code will be much more readable:

```
fetchOptionalDetails().ifPresent(details -> /* do something */);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Replacing a lot of code, just to replace if-statements is not helpful. Optionals are there to signify potentially nullary return values.

Comment: I was aware that Optional is designed to be used mainly as method return type but in my case fetchDetails method is provided by 3rd party jar which I don't have control, so wanted to check if writing the above way of coding is correct instead of if and null check

Comment: @springenthusiast In this case your code is fine. Although I would slightly change it. Please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Optional` from `fetchDetails()` makes more sense here. then you can directly check `ifPresent` and then proceed