# Optional way of if / else

Tags: java, option-type

I'm trying to avoid the traditional if / else block by using Java Optional.
But I still missing the understanding of how to implement the next requirement :

```
    if (x != null)
       foo1();
    else
       foo2();

public void foo1(){
   print("X not null");
}

public void foo2(){
   print("X is null");
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [jdk-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) you can use `ifPresentOrElse`

```
public void ifPresentOrElse​(Consumer<? super T> action,
                        Runnable emptyAction)
```

**Code**

```
Optional.ofNullable(x).ifPresentOrElse(x->foo1(), ()->foo2());
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying **to avoid** the traditional `if / else` block

That's the problem. There is no reason to rewrite the snippet you provided to `Optional`. You won't benefit from it in any way.

`if-else` is a control flow statement, while `Optional` is an util [that indicates the absence of a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) with a bunch of functional-like methods to handle it nicely.

If you are looking for a shortcut, or a more precise way to express it, go with a ternary operator.

```
print(x != null ? "X not null" : "X is null");
```

Otherwise, leave it as it is. You can always find something more interesting to play around with.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain how *avoiding the traditional `if/else` block* **is the problem**? The fact that "there's no reason to do it" doesn't necessarily make it *the problem*... Also, it's interesting that the conditional operator is suggested as a better alternative for getting rid of the `if/else` block.

Comment: but note with the void functions (which one might want to call), you cannot (At least I could not, maybe you have an idea, I got stuck) get the ternary operarator to do the trick unless you convert them to something that returns a meaningless value, like a boolean of true, that you then ignore.

Comment: @ernest_k Personally speaking, thinking about rewriting a harmless `if-else` to an unjustified `Optional` is a problem...

Comment: @JeremyKahan the methods may return `String` which would be the value to print: it wouldn't be *that* meaningless... The example looks rather superficial, though. So there is little to talk about...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yeah, that's a good point. It's consistent with the design principles I have been reading about that output is a side effect, and you don't want your lower level functions to have them.