# Is there a way to compare two Strings with each other using java streams?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

This method compares two strings. One of them comes from an object. If the strings match, the id is returned by the object.

```
    private static Long getDefaultKag(Long mandandId) {
        List<MandantKagAccountEntity> mandantKagAccountEntities = new MandantKagAccountManager().findAllKags(mandandId);
        for (MandantKagAccountEntity mandantKagAccountEntity : mandantKagAccountEntities) {
            if (mandantKagAccountEntity.getKagText().equals("Default_kag")) {
                return mandantKagAccountEntity.getMandantKagId();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there any way to solve this with streams? My approach, but I can't get any further.

```
    private static long getDefaultKag(Long mandandId) {
        return new MandantKagAccountManager().findAllKags(mandandId).stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getKagText().equals("Default_Kag"))
                ...
                ...
                ...
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? I would also like to know which of the two variants is more efficient for large amounts of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
...
...
...
```

with

```
.map(MandantKagAccountEntity::getMandantKagId)
.findFirst()
.orElse(null);
```

Comment: @Thilo you may want to return an `Optional<Long>`, or `OptionalLong` instead of `Long`

Comment: yeah maybe, i know that Optional, when filled, can not be zero anymore, right?. could you tell me the advantages if i would use Optional and how i can work with it afterwards? like normal?

Comment: @Thilo here's a good topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional

Answer (score 0):

I think it will do the trick

```
      private static long getDefaultKag(Long mandandId) {
                MandantKagAccountManager mandantKagAccountManager=new MandantKagAccountManager().findAllKags(mandandId).stream()
                        .filter(m -> m.getKagText().equals("Default_Kag")).findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);
              if(mandantKagAccountManager!=null)
                    return mandantKagAccountManager.getMandantKagId()
               return null;
}
```

Comment: downvoted because of `MandantKagAccountManager.getMandantKagId()` and the general idea

Comment: you may map the optional to `MandantKagAccountEntity::getMandantKagId` and get rid of the if