# Short version of check if the result of an object in not null then cast to boolean and set in Java

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

I have been looking for a short version of the following statement in Java:

```
if(headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT) !=null ) {
      record
          .setNativeHeadersPresent((boolean) headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT));
    }
```

If I would like to use `Optional.ofNullable` it doesn't work as I need to cast the object to boolean as well.

P.S: I am using Java8.

Comment: Considering `headers` as a `Map`, another way to resolve things would be `if(headers.containsKey(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT)) {
            record.setNativeHeadersPresent((boolean) headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT));
        }`. One doesn't always need an `Optional` to get rid of `null`s in the code.

Comment: You have three possible input conditions for the `NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT` value: `true`, `false` and `null`.  Are you saying that if the value is `null` you don't want to invoke `record.setNativeHeadersPresent()` at all?  Sounds like there's a logic leak there, or bad database design in that something called `NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT` does not sound like it should allow a `null` value.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes. That's right. NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT is a message header that I received from an external party, I cannot be sure that always it is going to be provided. However, the downstream system only accepts 'true' and 'false', so I just want to say that if it doesn't exist, don't set the value as null is not accepted.

Comment: If I understand you, you want to map input {true,false,null} -> {true,false} with both input null and input false mapping to output false. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's not what `Optional.ofNullable` for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional), but I will share how it can be done because I love method references.

```
Optional.ofNullable(headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT))
        .map(boolean.class::cast)
        .ifPresent(record::setNativeHeadersPresent);
```

Since you've got a `Map<String, String>`, [`Map#getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) could be an option.

```
record.setNativeHeadersPresent(
    Boolean.parseBoolean(
        headers.getOrDefault(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT, "false")
    )
);
```

Comment: Do we have any other way of addressing that in Java without using Optional, then? I am a really big fan of if you could do something it doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: @Alin we have control flow statements which are fine in most cases. They keep things simple and to the point.

Comment: @Alin  you may want to use [`Map#getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)). I assume you get a String, so it would be `record.setNativeHeadersPresent(Boolean.parseBoolean(headers.getOrDefault(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT, "false")));`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko `Map#getOrDefault()` returns the default only if the key is not present, but will return `null` if the map permits null values and a null value was associated with the key.

Comment: Why does your second example suddenly assume that the map values are strings? Further mind the difference between calling `setNativeHeadersPresent` when the value is present and always calling `setNativeHeadersPresent`… By the way, it must be `Boolean.class::cast` instead of `boolean.class::cast`, as you can not cast an object to a primitive type.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to implement this mapping

```
Input  ->  Output
-----      ------
true       true
false      false
null       false
```

If you MUST use `Optional`, the most succinct way of expressing this is

```
Optional.ofNullable(headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT)).orElse(false);
```

However, you don't need `Optional` at all.  The following will do what you are asking for:

```
Boolean nhp = headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT);
record.setNativeHeadersPresent((nhp == null) ? false : nhp);
```

If you want it in one statement (at the expense of invoking `headers.get()` twice):

```
record.setNativeHeadersPresent(
    (headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT) == null) 
        ? false 
        : headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT));
```

***Important Note:*** The use of `Map#getOrDefault(...,false)` may not work.  If the `Map` implementation supports `null` values, then `getOrDefault()` can still return `null` if a `null` value was associated with that key.  (i.e. at some point `put(key,value)` with `value==null` was executed). The `default` value is returned only if the key was not present in the map.

Comment: I appreciate your approach using a conditional expression. With all the fuss about functional programming in Java, ppl. tend to miss that a conditional expression **is** the functional equivalent of if-else :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only thing is the Map is a type of <String, Object> and I need to cast it to boolean as well.

Comment: @Alin If you really cannot narrow down the value type beyond just `Object` then you also need to handle the case where the value cannot be converted to `boolean`. I presume you want `false` then. Other than that this approach still works, you just have to test for type compatibility as well as `null`.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann still, any compound boolean expression containing a `boolean` literal can be expressed without. So instead of `(nhp == null) ? false : nhp`, you can simply use `nhp != null && nhp`.

Comment: @Alin then, simplest solution: `record.setNativeHeadersPresent(Boolean.TRUE.equals(headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT)));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a simple call to [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) should work:

```
Optional.ofNullable(headers.get(BinderHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS_PRESENT))
    .ifPresent(
        x -> record.setNativeHeadersPresent((boolean)x)
    )
```

It doesn't matter what you do with the optional (whether you cast it or not), because `ifPresent` accepts a "function" as its parameter. You can pass in code that does whatever you like.