# Shortcut for null-check before method invocation in java

Tags: java, null

When writing simple or complex java code, it seems quite common to write code like this:

```
if (obj != null) {
    obj.someMethod();
}
```

Or more specific:

```
Foo someValue = null;
if (valueObject != null) {
    someValue = valueObject.getSomeValue();
}
```

Which would mean `someValue` stays null when the Value Object is null. Now, as I encounter this type of code quite often (and it increases cognitive/cyclic complexity), I wondered if there is some way to simplify these statements in any way. I looked for a solution which looks like:

```
Foo someValue = nullOrCompute(valueObject, valueObject::getSomeValue);
```

After some research it seemed that Java does not provide a similar feature. So, as a test, I wrote the shortcut myself, which looks like this:

```
public class NullHelper
{
    private static <T> boolean check(T object)
    {
        return object == null;
    }

    public static <T> void nullOrExecute(T object, Consumer<T> func)
    {
        if (!check(object))
            func.accept(object);
    }

    public static <T, R> R nullOrCompute(T object, Function<T, R> func)
    {
        return check(object)
            ? null
            : func.apply(object);
    }

    public static <T, P0, R> R nullOrCompute(T object, BiFunction<T, P0, R> func, P0 param0)
    {
        return check(object)
            ? null
            : func.apply(object, param0);
    }

    // more params
}
```

Note that you'd have to write your own "`NFunction`" Interfaces if you wanted to include versions with more params because Java does not provide `TriFunction`s or higher.

**My Question is:**

Is this code a good way to simplify a big existing codebase? And if not, is it because there is a more convenient Java feature which I don't know, or is it beacuse I need to improve my custom version (and how)?

Please keep in mind that I am not talking about the most convenient solution *in general*, but for a solution that can be applied to a big existing codebase.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "it seems quite common to write code" with NULL. The root cause is that you use NULL. This is a [terrible practice](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html) in an object-oriented paradigm and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Boris So you suggest refactoring the entire large codebase to get rid of nulls? Sure, nulls aren't great, but of all terrible object-oriented practices, this is far from the worst one. NullPointerExceptions are some of the easiest problems to find and solve in typical code.

Comment: @Malt that is right, I am not looking for the perfect paradigm, but for a simple and scalable solution

Comment: @RaphaelTarita I've put my 2 cents in... It's unpopular, just the ideas to think over. Have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
check(foo)
nullOrExecute(foo, consumer)
nullOrCompute(foo, mapper)
nullOrCompute(foo, func, param)
```

Equivalent code using optionals:

```
Optional.ofNullable(foo).isPresent();
Optional.ofNullable(foo).ifPresent(consumer);
Optional.ofNullable(foo).map(mapper)
```

Comment: Does this also work for methods with multiple parameters? By the way, this seems like the solution I am looking for, thank you

Comment: @RaphaelTarita: Yes, you can use a lambda that closes over other values to pass multiple parameters into the methods you're trying to call. `Optional.ofNullable(foo).map(f -> f.getSomething(oneValue, anotherValue))`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It seems that I have found the solution I have looked for

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`Optional<>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead of `null` to represent something that can legitimately not be present.

```
Optional<Bar> valueObject = getValueObject();
Optional<Foo> someValue = valueObject.map(o -> o.getSomeValue());
```

`Optional<>` has a handful of methods (`map`, `ifPresent`, `orElse`, and `orElseGet`) to take different actions depending on whether it has a value.

If you want to keep your changes restricted to smaller scopes (one method, or even one line), you can still accomplish what you're looking for without needing to write custom utility methods.

```
Foo someValue = Optional.ofNullable(valueObject).map(Bar::getSomeValue).orElse(null);
```

But I think what you'll find is that if you start this way, the `Optional<>` paradigm will naturally spread over time and improve the code quality of your project as a whole.

Comment: the OP pointed out that it's a big existing codebase, so rewriting the return type of every method from `T` to `Optional<T>` would be tedious

Comment: @Tobilko that is right. I knew about Optional<> (and the perks to use a non-null language like Rust), but in my opinion, this is probably way too much refactoring for the massive codebase, mostly because if you want to do it properly, the problems spread so you have to implement the technique everywhere

Comment: You can still leverage Optional without changing method signatures. Using the `ofNullable()` method, you can still turn most of your null-checking logic into one-liners and use a more widely-accepted paradigm than writing your own utilities.

Comment: I am pro Optional, +1. It is a clear cut, changes will not coincedently forget a null handling, as the API will change over time. Code analysis tools will warn against nullables. It is a clean refactoring you will not be able to achieve with null utils.

Comment: @RaphaelTarita: I updated my answer to show that you can still restrict your changes to a single line if that's what you want. You don't have to refactor everything. But what you describe as "the problems spread", I personally see as "the good pattern spreads to make real problems more visible."

Comment: @RaphaelTarita it's hard to call "wrapping a value into another class just to use its methods" a [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) technique...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, I really could use it in the restricted version. And yes, it would probably be better to refactor the whole codebase to Optionals. But with the size of the codebase I am talking about, this could literally take years to refactor. I am trying to find a solution which I can use in a single location in the codebase, so the team can review the up - and downsides of the shortcut. Then we can talk about applying it in other code locations

Comment: @RaphaelTarita: I totally understand. I'd be the last person to advocate refactoring your whole code base to stop using nulls all at once. That's why I think you should start small, changing the pieces of code that you're already planning to change. The spread of the Optional pattern will happen naturally and organically over time.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that's essentially the plan. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

`Optional` is faster and allows chaining of non-present fields.

Entirely with legacy nullable objects:

```
Foo someValue = Optional.ofNullable(valueObject).map(Bar::getSomeValue).orElse(null);
```

Partly:

```
Optional<Foo> someValue = Optional.ofNullable(valueObject).map(Bar::getSomeValue);
```

Ported to Optionals:

```
Optional<Foo> someValue = valueObject.map(Bar::getSomeValue);
```

Advantages:

```
Optional<Baz> someValue = valueObject.map(Bar::getSomeValue).map(Fuz::getSub);

someValue.ifPresent(v -> ... non-null v);
```

Code style checkers can now finely detect nullables and nonnullables. One may also annotate non-nullables. One may incrementally move to Optionals, just as you intended on extended null handling.