# How to perform Operations on Optional OfNullable and handle Null

Tags: java-8, option-type, nullable

I've a nullable field where I want to perform operation, if not null. return null otherwise.
I can write it in plain Java as

```
return (myfield != null)? myfield.getData() :null;
```

How can I write the same code in one line with Optional

Something like below. 
**Below code is not a correct code, just want to ask the correct version of it**

```
return Optional.ofNullable(myfield).map(Functionas.identity().getData()).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Why do you want to make long your way!? what is the benefit of usage optional here? go with the first solution.

Comment: @HadiJ Sure, Wasn't sure, if this will be long. that's why I asked..

Comment: see this, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional

Comment: This is not the type of problem Optional was intended to solve rather using Optional here would be an *overkill*, *less memory friendly* and to some extent less readable via the Optional approach too.

so conclusion is I'd stick with your approach of:

    `return myfield != null ? myfield.getData() : null;`

as it's short and sweet and reads well.