# Representing undefined value in REST API request in Java 8 using Jackson

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, undefined

I have a `PATCH` REST endpoint, exposing a JSON interface, which can be used to partially update an entity, based on the attributes which are actually sent in the body.

Let's consider a sample class representing the entity:

```
class Account {
    private UUID accountUuid;
    private UUID ownerUuid;
    private String number;
    private String alias;

    // constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

where `accountUuid`, `ownerUuid` and `number` are required properties, and `alias` is optional. Additionally I have a command class for updating said account:

```
class UpdateAccountCommand {
    private UUID accountUuid;
    private String number;
    private String alias;

    // constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

For my `PATCH` endpoint, e.g. `PATCH /accounts/{account-uuid}`, I'd like to implement a functionality, that only properties actually sent in the request are changed:

```
// this should only update the account number
{"number": "123456"}

// this should only update the alias, by setting it to null
{"alias": null}

// this shouldn't update anything
{}
```

For **required** properties, this is fairly easy to do. After deserialisation from the JSON string to `UpdateAccountCommand` instance using Jackson, I simply check if a required property is `null`, and when it's not `null`, I update the given property.

However the situation complicates with **optional** properties, since the `alias` property is `null` in both cases:

- when the request body explicitly specifies the `alias` as null,
- when the `alias` property is not specified in the request body at all.

How can I model these optional properties, so that I can indicate this *removable* mechanism?

Comment: use a Map instead of DTO?

Comment: @Adrian Not a very elegant solution, since the only map that would work would be `Map<String, Object>`, giving you no information about available properties (keys) as well as their types. Nothing would prevent anyone to e.g. pass an object in a place where you would expect a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution would be to introduce some sort of a wrapper, which would not only contain the raw value (e.g. for the `alias: string` property), but also a `boolean`, indicating whether a property was specified in the body or not. This would require you to write a [custom deserialisation](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) mechanism, which can be a tedious work.

Since the question is about Java 8, for Java 8 and newer, I recommend using a nullable [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), which works pretty much out of the box with Jackson.

For optional (removable fields), you change the raw values by wrapping them in optional:

```
class UpdateAccountCommand {
    private UUID accountUuid;
    private String number;
    private Optional<String> alias;

    // constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

In order for Jackson to work with `Optional<*>` fields correctly, the [`Jdk8Module`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jdk8/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.html) module has to be registered to the object mapper, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

The following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

    String withNewAliasS = "{\"alias\":\"New Alias\"}";
    String withNullAliasS = "{\"alias\":null}";
    String withoutPropertyS = "{}";

    UpdateAccountCommand withNewAlias = objectMapper.readValue(withNewAliasS, UpdateAccountCommand.class);
    if (withNewAlias.getAlias() != null && withNewAlias.getAlias().isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("withNewAlias specified new alias.");
    }

    UpdateAccountCommand withNullAlias = objectMapper.readValue(withNullAliasS, UpdateAccountCommand.class);
    if (withNullAlias.getAlias() != null && !withNullAlias.getAlias().isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("withNullAlias will remove an alias.");
    }

    UpdateAccountCommand withoutProperty = objectMapper.readValue(withoutPropertyS, UpdateAccountCommand.class);
    if (withoutProperty.getAlias() == null) {
        System.out.println("withoutProperty did not contain alias property on input at all.");
    }
}
```

then prints out this to the console:

```
withNewAlias specified new alias.
withNullAlias will remove an alias.
withoutProperty did not contain alias property on input at all.
```

Comment: [having an Optional in a class field or in a data structure, is considered a misuse of the API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/8198056)

Answer (score 0):

you can add an additional boolean property which says if the optional property was present in request

```
class UpdateAccountCommand {
  //...
  private String alias;
  @JsonIgnore
  private boolean isAliasSet;

  @JsonProperty
  public void setAlias(String value) {
     this.alias = value;
     this.isAliasSet = true;
  }
}
```

the setter is called only when "alias" is present, be it null or with value

Comment: I don't think this is much of an improvement. It unfortunately leads to exactly what I am trying to avoid, writing unnecessary code, basically polluting a class and making it twice as large for optional fields. To fix this, a wrapper would then need to be introduced (as I am mentioning in my own answer), you need to provide custom deserialisation mechanism, and how is then having a `CustomOptional<String>` better than `Optional<String>`, when the latter provides the desired mechanism pretty much out of the box?