# How to check the field of an object on NPE and condition simultaneously through Optional? And if everything is ok, do nothing, else throw exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use Java 8 and have an issue with how to check objects through Optional.
It should be like

```
Optional.ofNullable(person)
        .map(Person::getAge)
        .filter(age -> age > 25)
        .orElseThrow(new CustomException())
```

However, this code returns the value, but I don't need this.
How fix it? Code should be like this

```
If (noNPE && person.getAge() > 25) {
       // do nothing
} else {
       throw new CustomException();
}
```

I don't need return value due to sonar throw warnings.

Comment: what's wrong with the second snippet? Replace `noNPE` with `person!=null` and you're done

Comment: I need one more check in this case, that person.getAge() is not null. After that code is ugly and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Just because `Optional` exists, doesn't mean you should use it everywhere. A simple null-check (e.g. `if (person == null || person.getAge() <= 25) throw new CustomException();`) is IMHO far simpler and more readable than using `Optional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a proper use of Optional.  Optional is not a general replacement for `if` statements.  See [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional).

It’s really not so bad if you just write:

```
if (person != null && person.getAge() != null && person.getAge() < 25) {
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

But if you don’t like that, you can refactor the check into a new method in the Person class:

```
public void checkAge() {
    if (getAge() != null && getAge() < 25) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}

// Other class:

if (person != null) {
    person.checkAge();
}
```

Or, you can add a method to Person which only does the age logic:

```
public boolean tooYoung() {
    return (getAge() != null && getAge() < 25);
}

// Other class:

if (person != null && person.tooYoung()) {
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs to be fixed in your code is the API usage, otherwise it won't compile:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(person)
        .map(Person::getAge)
        .filter(age -> age > 25)
        .orElseThrow(CustomException::new);
```

(`orElseThrow()` needs to be fed with a `Supplier`)

There is no problem in ignoring the returned value.

Try `@SuppressWarning("unused")` or `//NOSONAR` to silence SonarQubes false positive.

Comment: "The only thing"? The actual thing that needs to be fixed here is misuse of APIs in general. `if (person == null || person.getAge() <= 25) throw new CustomException();` is a lot simpler.

Comment: @rzwitserloot That's what I would call a style improvement. :-)
As the question targetted `Optional`, in a real-world scenario, it also could have been returned from another method, so you may simply continue using its API.

Answer (score -3):

You could leverage `ifPresent()` as the predication in the `if` statement:

```java
if Optional.ofNullable(person)
        .map(Person::getAge)
        .filter(age -> age > 25)
        .orElseThrow(new CustomException())
        .isPresent() {
       // do nothing
} else {
       throw new CustomException();
}
```

Comment: `orElseThrow` returns type `T`, not `Optional<T>`, so you cannot call `isPresent()`.