# "Optional value should only be accessed after calling isPresent()" although checked in if for multiple values

Tags: java, sonarqube

I receive a Customer object which contains lastName and firstName. In the conversion I check if both values are not empty and then pass them into the DTO:

```
if (customer.getFirstName().isPresent() && customer.getLastName().isPresent()) {
      final String firstName = customer.getFirstName().get();
      final String lastName = customer.getLastName().get();
      // do assignment
}
```

But I still get the Sonar message *Optional value should only be accessed after calling isPresent()*.

Am I missing something here or is this a false positive?

Comment: What if, `getFirstName` returns something different the second time you call it?

Comment: Using `ifPresent` with `get` defeats the purpose of using an `Optional`. A null check is clearer to read in this case.

Comment: Good points. In this case it is not possible to return something else, but I get the point.

Comment: `Optional` should not be used as a property type.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional which has an authoritative answer on this subject.

Comment: If I'm just passing it around, there is no benefit in unpacking it when I have to do the null checks or packing it in Optional later again. But this has nothing to do with my question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using **ifPresent** :

```
customer.getFirstName().ifPresent(name1->
  customer.getLastName().ifPresent(name2->
      final String firstName = name1;
      final String lastName = name2;
  );
);
```

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks!