# Java - code will always throw a Null Pointer Exception when no Property is present?

Tags: java, string, exception, properties, option-type

I have inherited the following java code, that gets the value of a `property` from a `properties file`:

```
    String personName = this.properties.getFilePropertty("person.name");
    if (personName != null) {
       // do something else
    } else {
        // do something
    }
```

The intended behavior in the above flow is that `personName` will either be retrieved from the properties file or will be returned as `null` if its not there, and handled accordingly.

However when the property is not there an exception is thrown in the `getFileProperty()` method (shown below).

How can I fix this to have the intended behavior?

**getFileProperty():**

```
            public String getFileProperty(String name) throws SystemPropertiesException {
            
            return Optional.ofNullable( this.properties.getProperty(name, null) )
            .orElseThrow(()->new PropertiesException("Can not get property!"));
            
             }
```

Note - the `getProperty()` method being called in the code above is [java utils getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: `Optional` should not be used as a replacement for `if` statements.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your code in a try catch block.

```
try {
    String personName = this.properties.getFileProperty("person.name");
    // do something else
} catch (PropertiesException exception) {
    // do something
}
```

Edit: Alternatively provide a defaultValue to `.getFileProperty()`

```
String personName = this.properties.getFilePropertty("person.name", "NO_VALUE_FOUND");
if (!personName.equals("NO_VALUE_FOUND")) {
    // do something else
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, so if an exception is thrown that means there is no property - so I need to handle it accordingly

Comment: It's always good practice to wrap functions that might throw an error in a try-catch block. I also just checked the documentation of the .getFileProperty() function and you can provide a defaultValue as a second argument. You could use that to properly handle what should happen if no key is found. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch

```
try{
    String personName = this.properties.getFilePropertty("person.name");
    //if it's not null there will be no exception so you can directly use the personName 
    
}catch(SystemPropertiesException ex){
    //else there is an exception to handle here 
}
```