# How to map an instance of type Object to specific Class in Java using Stream API

Tags: java, object, casting, java-stream, mapping

I've encountered the following problem:

If I map an object in a stream to a specific class in Java, the java stream API does not recognize a specific object after the mapping and still assumes it is an object. What am I doing wrong, and is there a way to solve this without potential class cast exceptions?

Here is the code example:

```
public class MyMapper {

        MyMapper() {
            Object someObject = new Person();
            final var listOfObjects = List.of(someObject);
            final var listOfPerson = toListOfPerson(listOfObjects);
        }

        List<Optional<Person>> toListOfPerson(Object object) {
            return ((List) object).stream()
                           .map(this::toPerson)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        Optional<Person> toPerson(Object object) {

            if (object instanceof Person) {
                return Optional.of((Person) object);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        public class Person {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to keep the collection of *optional objects* which could be potentially empty, it almost the same as storing `null` values.

If you think for some reason that `List<Optional<Person>>` is good idea, I recommend you to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional/23464794). A quote from the answer by Stuart Marks (JDK developer):

> I'm sure somebody could come up with some contrived cases where they
> really want to **store an Optional** in a field or a **collection**, but in
> general, **it is best to avoid doing this**.

Optional was introduced in the JDK as a limited mechanism to represent a **nullable return value**. That is its only purpose, other cases of usage of optional objects like optional method arguments, fields, collections of optionals are considered to be antipattern.

You have to unpack your `Optional`s in the stream:

```
public List<Person> toListOfPerson(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof List<?>)) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    
    return ((List<?>) object).stream()
        .map(this::toPerson)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. In my use case there is an extra treatment of "persons" that do not exist. But I agree to your comment and just throw a class cast exception instead of using optionales.

Comment: @TheBohne *extra treatment of "persons" that do not exist* - Then you might consider implementing the *Null-object pattern* to handle this case. Also note that *instanceof* checks is a *code-smell*. If you are working with a legacy system that returns you objects, that understandable. But it better to avoid it and design the logic in such a way that you don't need type-checks and down-casting.

Answer (score 3):

cast it to a typed List and then your *.map(this::toPerson)* will "accept" the element of this List

```
List<Optional<Person>> toListOfPerson(Object object) {
            return ((List<Object>) object).stream()
                    .map(this::toPerson)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```