# Best way to return ResponseEntity with data, empty and error in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a generic approach that can be used for each return types from Service to Controller in my Spring Boot app. After searching and reading several threads and articles, I see that I need an approach with `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations.

For exception, I created the following class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FileUploadException extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleMaxSizeException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
                   .body(new ResponseMessage("Too large!"));
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure if it is ok and how I should treat `Optional.empty()` results in my Service and Controller. So, could you please suggest me a proper approach or give an example that is used for exception, result with data and result with `Optional.empty()` ?

Please note that I have the following articles, but they are too old and I am not sure if these approach are still good or there is a better approach with the new versions of Spring Boot, etc?

[Guide to Spring Boot REST API Error Handling](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling)

[Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Does anybody else never used a generic approach for these return types in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

Specific ExceptionHandler:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

  @Autowired private ProductService productService; 
  
  @GetMapping("/{code}")
  public ResponseEntity<Product> findByCode(@PathVariable String code) {
    return productService.findByCode(code).map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseThrow(() -> NoContentException::new);
  }

   @ExceptionHandler(NoContentException.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleNoContent(NoContentException e) {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(new ResponseMessage("No data"));
   }
}
```

Common ExceptionHandler:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

  @Autowired private ProductService productService; 
  
  @GetMapping("/{code}")
  public ResponseEntity<Product> findByCode(@PathVariable String code) {
    return productService.findByCode(code).map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseThrow(() -> NoContentException::new);
  }
}
```

Plus:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleMaxSizeException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage("Too large!"));
   }

   @ExceptionHandler(NoContentException.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleNoContent(NoContentException e) {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(new ResponseMessage("No data"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but I am looking for a more generic way as mentioned on the given link at the end of the question. Do they provide a solution for this problem? I could not be sure as they were written many years ago. Any idea?

Comment: You can put the method `handleNoContent` into the `@ControllerAdvice ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

Comment: The second approach seems to good, I will try and inform you voted up ;) On the other hand, I am wondering the service method. Is that possible to handle exception in the service method and not return `ResponseEntity` from service (maybe return a Dto, but not sure if it works for all of 3 situations that I mentioned). Any idea?