# Combine the Two Lines of code initializing and populating a List into a Single Statement in Java 8?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream, option-type

I have a list of user id `pmUserIds`. For each *id* in the list I'm making a call `getUserByUserId()` and placing the result in a list of type `List<Optional<User>>`.

I want to combine these 2 lines into a single statement:

```
List<Optional<User>> pmUsers = new ArrayList<>();

pmUserIds.forEach(userId -> pmUsers.add(userRepository.getUserByUserId(userId)));
```

Something like that wouldn't work:

```
List<Optional<User>> pmUsers  = pmUserIds.forEach(userId -> pmUsers.add(userRepository.getUserByUserId(userId)));
```

It will say that `pmUsers` not have been initiated. Is there any way we could do this in single line?

Comment: Try `map` and `collect`.

Comment: Create a `public User[] userRepository.getUsersByUserId(list of user ids)` (note the plural: one method that returns an array of all matched users, without null elements) and then create the ArrayList with that as argument? (with proper generics of course. No `<>`, you know what goes in this list)

Comment: Yes, just delete the linebreak. Perfect solution achieved !

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stream.map` instead of `forEach`, then convert to `List` with `collect`:

```
List<Optional<User>> pmUsers = pmUserIds.stream()
        .map(userId -> userRepository.getUserByUserId(userId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That's still not one line (except you want a really long line), but it's somewhat clearer what the code does that with separate initialization and `forEach`. You may also use a method reference instead of that lambda, i.e. `.map(userRepository::getUserByUserId)`

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is not viable because method `forEach()` is `void`. To do the job in a single statement, you need a [**Stream**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).

But there is more to it.

Storing `Optional` objects into a `Collection` is an **antipattern**. It almost the same as storing `null` references because *optional* not necessarily contains a value.

Both `null` and *empty optional* are meant to represent the absence of data and nothing else. If one of them has a separate meaning in your application (apart from *"no value"*), it's a smell.

If you need to fire a particular action when a call `getUserByUserId()` returns an *empty optional*, then do it right after receiving the *optional* instead of placing it to the list (and by the way, Stream is not the right tool when you need to perform some side-effects along the way, it would be better to stick with plain loops).

Here's a small quote from the [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/17949945) by *@Stuart Marks*, Java and OpenJDK developer:

> I'm sure somebody could come up with some contrived cases where they really want to **store** an `Optional` in a **field** or a **collection**, but in general, it is best to **avoid doing this**.

I suggest you to check the presence of value in the `Optional` right on the spot (in the stream) and then "unpack" *non-empty optional objects*.

That's how it might look like:

```
List<User> pmUsers  = pmUserIds.stream()
    .map(userRepository::getUserByUserId) // Stream<Optional<User>>
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)                   // Stream<User>
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or .collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
```