# Reading Optional data with Jackson object mapper

Tags: java, jackson, option-type

I have a json String and it needs to be converted to Optional data type.

Getting Optional.empty as the response. Is it possible to get the Optional here with the correct value.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.sams.interceptor.model.mixins.HttpStatusMixIn;
import com.sams.interceptor.model.mixins.ResponseEntityMixin;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class App2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr = "{\"value\":{\"id\":123}}";
        Optional<Student> abc = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr,java.util.Optional.class);
        System.out.println(abc);
    }

}

class Student {
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). First of all, `Optional` was **not** designed for such use cases (see [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/17949945)), and secondly (as a consequence) it's not possible to do you was trying to do with Jackson in a straightforward way.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a more **elaborate description** of your use-case. I.e. explain what you were intended to do with the `Optional<Student>` further? Should it be returned from the method a stored somewhere? These details would help in to provide useful feedback.