# How best to populate a variable using Optional?

Tags: java, option-type

I'm using an optional ID here but I don't like having to declare TWO variables to receive the data.  What is a more concise way to accomplish this without having to declare an extra OptionalOrg variable?

```
    Optional<Organization> optionalOrg;
    Organization org;

    if (request.getOrgId() != null) {
        optionalOrg = organizationRepository.findById(request.getOrgId());
    } else {
        optionalOrg = organizationRepository.findById(DEFAULT_ORG);
    }

    if (optionalOrg.isPresent()) {
        org = optionalOrg.get();
    } else {
        throw new ClientException("Org not found);
    }
```

Comment: @OleV.V  well I tend to agree Optional gains you nothing, but then why does JPA make findById return an Optional as the standard type for a repository?   If I change the default method then I have tons of places through the codebase that also have to be changed?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Sure, get an `Optional` from there. And use its `orElseThrow` method for getting its value or throwing your exception as shown in each of the answers. Don't use `isPresent()` and `get()`.

Comment: `Organization org = organizationRepository .findById(Objects.requireNonNullElse(request.getOrgId(), DEFAULT_ORG)) .orElseThrow(() -> new ClientException("Org not found"));`

Answer (score 4):

[`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) can be used to get the contained value, or throw an exception of your choice if empty.

```
org = organizationRepository
  .findById(id)
  .orElseThrow(() -> new ClientException("Org not found"));
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I've written Java code, but I'm pretty sure the arrow operator is supposed to be `->`, not `=>`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yep, you're right. Been awhile since I've written Java too :P

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do that:

```java
var orgId = Objects.requireNonNullElse(request.getOrId(), DEFAULT_ORG);
var org = organizationRepository.findById(orgId)
                                .orElseThrow(() ->  new ClientException("Org not found));
```

Use the appropriate type instead of `var` if not Java 11++ and similar function for `requireNonNullElse`.

Comment: The second line of code is good.  The first line is not.  Optional is *not* a general replacement for if/else (or `?`/`:`).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional for comments from Java’s designers on how Optional is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

try this but i'm not 100% sure..

```
Optional<Organization> optionalOrg = Optional.ofNullable(request.getOrgId())
    .flatMap(id -> organizationRepository.findById(id))
    .or(() -> organizationRepository.findById(DEFAULT_ORG));

Organization org = optionalOrg.orElseThrow(() -> new ClientException("Org not found"));
```

Comment: Now we’re at it, an alternative is `Optional .ofNullable(request.getOrgId()) .or(() -> DEFAULT_ORG) .flatMap(id -> organizationRepository.findById(id))`. It avoids the repetition of the call to `findById()`, so I would prefer it.

Comment: @OleV.V. it’s `orElseGet(() -> DEFAULT_ORG)`, as `or` expects a supplier of an optional, but for a simple variable access, I’d use `.orElse(DEFAULT_ORG)` instead of `.orElseGet(() -> DEFAULT_ORG)`…