# How to Access a Deeply Nested Object's Property in a Clean Way?

Tags: java, oop

an A object contains a B object, which contains a C object, which in turn contains a D object. I need to access the "name" property of the D object starting from the A object.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

`a.getB().getC().getD().getName();`

I can get the "name" value this way, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Any examples or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define *better*?

Comment: I recently learned about the Law of Demeter and it seems that my current code might be violating this principle. Given the object structure described in my question, what approaches should I use to adhere to the Law of Demeter?

Comment: @pilming: Within any given instance along that chain, is there a meaningful way to semantically describe the value being fetched?  That description could simply be the name of a getter method which encapsulates this logic (and any error checking therein).

Comment: As Martin Fowler write, [I'd prefer it to be called the Occasionally Useful Suggestion of Demeter](https://twitter.com/martinfowler/status/1649793241).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! They helped me organize my thoughts.

Comment: This chain method call - `a.getB().getC().getD().getName();`, gives the impression that you are using objects as data carriers (POJOs, DTOs, there are many names). You could hide this in a method `getNameOfD()`, but this will treat the symptom, not the cause. The underlying problem is that you are violating the principle `tell, don't ask` - you don't tell your objects `doThis()` and let *them* handle doing it, you ask them about their state, extract it outside and *you* are doing it.

Comment: I would make the code more robust. Null Checks for example. If you use Java 8+ feel free to use the Optional Class.

Comment: @AztecCodes [That’s not what Optional is for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is good but there is a risk that other objects called are null null. To prevent this you can use `NullPointerExceptions`.  You could use optional checks or explicit null checks:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a.getB())
    .map(B::getC)
    .map(C::getD)
    .map(D::getName)
    .orElse(null);
```

I've seen also in the commentaries' suggestion of [Low of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). That I understand that, this is a guideline aimed at reducing coupling between components in software development. In the context of object-oriented programming, it suggests that an object should only interact with its immediate "friends" and not with strangers or the internal details of other objects.

When applied to method calls, the Law of Demeter typically means an object method should only call methods of:

1. The object itself (this).
2. Objects passed as arguments to the method.
3. Any objects it creates/instantiates.
4. Its direct component objects (often referred to as its properties or fields).

So I tried to do this using this principes:

```
// Class A encapsulates a reference to an instance of class B.
public class A {
    private B b;

    // This method demonstrates adherence to the Law of Demeter by only interacting with its direct friend, B.
    // It checks if B is non-null and then delegates the responsibility of getting D's name to B.
    // This avoids directly accessing the internals of B or its relations.
    public String getDName() {
        if (b != null) {
            return b.getDName();
        }
        return null; // Returns null if B is null, avoiding a NullPointerException.
    }
}

// Class B encapsulates a reference to an instance of class C.
public class B {
    private C c;

    // Similar to class A, this method follows the Law of Demeter by interacting only with its direct friend, C.
    // It delegates the task of retrieving D's name to C, thus not violating the principle by reaching out to C's internals.
    public String getDName() {
        if (c != null) {
            return c.getDName();
        }
        return null; // Handles the case where C is null gracefully.
    }
}

// Class C encapsulates a reference to an instance of class D.
public class C {
    private D d;

    // Adhering to the Law of Demeter, this method interacts only with its immediate friend, D.
    // It directly retrieves D's name if D is not null, demonstrating a direct and simple interaction with its component.
    public String getDName() {
        if (d != null) {
            return d.getName();
        }
        return null; // Protects against null D references.
    }
}

// Class D holds a name property.
public class D {
    private String name;

    // Direct accessor method for the name property.
    // This is the endpoint of the delegation chain and does not need to follow LoD principles as it does not delegate further.
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is known as the "Fluent Interface" or "Method Chaining" pattern.

Instead of calling multiple getter methods one after the other, you can create a single method that returns the nested object, and then call the desired property or method on that nested object.

Here's a simple example to illustrate this approach:

```java
// Assuming the following class structure:
class A {
    private B b;
    // Constructor, getters, and setters

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

class B {
    private C c;
    // Constructor, getters, and setters

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
}

class C {
    private D d;
    // Constructor, getters, and setters

    public D getD() {
        return d;
    }
}

class D {
    private String name;
    // Constructor, getters, and setters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Instead of doing:

```java
A a = new A();
String name = a.getB().getC().getD().getName();
```

You can create a method in the `A` class that returns the `D` object directly:

```java
class A {
    // ...

    public D getNestedD() {
        return getB().getC().getD();
    }
}
```

Now, you can access the `name` property of the `D` object like this:

```java
A a = new A();
String name = a.getNestedD().getName();
```

This approach is more readable and easier to maintain because you only need to call one method (`getNestedD()`) to access the deeply nested object's property. If the nested object structure changes in the future, you only need to update the `getNestedD()` method in the `A` class, without modifying the code that uses it.

Additionally, you can create similar methods in the `B` and `C` classes to access their nested objects more easily:

```java
class B {
    // ...

    public D getNestedD() {
        return getC().getD();
    }
}

class C {
    // ...

    public D getD() {
        return d;
    }
}
```

This way, you can access the `name` property of the `D` object starting from any of the enclosing objects, making the code more flexible and maintainable:

```java
A a = new A();
String name = a.getNestedD().getName();       // Access from A
String name = a.getB().getNestedD().getName(); // Access from B
String name = a.getB().getC().getD().getName(); // Access from C
```