Refactoring if-else inside a consumer in an Optional
I have a block of code like follows:
    @Nullable SomeUrn someUrn = Optional.ofNullable(somePage)
        .map(somePage::someEntity)
        .map(entity -> {
          if(entity.isMember()) {
            return entity.getMember();
          } else {
            LOG.error("Expected a member but received " + entity);
            return null;
          }})
        .orElse(null);

Is there a better way to handle the error case in Java 8?
I tried
.map(entity -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(entity)
        .map(ent -> ent.getMember())
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            LOG.error("Expected a member but received " + ent); 
            return null;
        })
.orElse(null);

but I lose the entity to log and it's more complicated than the if-else anyway

You could extract that second map block into it's own method and that might make it look a little cleaner...but looks fine to me but that's just opinion for whatever that's worth (very little)...

Which parts of your first block are you hoping to reduce/remove? It looks fine to me. I might even do away with the first map, and just do everything in the second one. (Also "exception" in Java is a specific thing, and your if-else doesn't deal with it; so for clarity, I wouldn't call this an exception.)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  And also take the [tour] and read [ask].

One of the ideas could be to try declaring a Predicate<Entity such as
Predicate<Entity> loggingPredicate = entity -> {
        if(entity.isMember()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // do something with the entity like logging
            return false;
        }
 };

and further make use of it like:
Optional.ofNullable(somePage)
        .map(somePage::someEntity)
        .filter(loggingPredicate)
        .map(entity -> entity.getMember())
        .orElse(null);


return somePage == null ? null :
  somePage.someEntity().getMember();

You're not writing functional code (for any reasonable definition of 'functional') or making a system that is 'optional' based because its got null all over it. The above code is faster, more readable, and far simpler to understand. Going from some nullable entity to an optional just to go through a series of mapping steps, only to end it all with .orElse(null) is pretty much always a code smell. If you want to get rid of null, then get rid of it, orElse(null) means you failed in the endeavour. If you do not want to get rid of null, do not use Optional except for the purpose it was designed for.
Optional was designed for a very constrained domain: As the type of stream termianl ops. Which this isn't. The java community sometimes also uses it as the return type of methods to indicate that they may not return a value. However, even that also quite limited domain (again, this code you are writing is not in it, and should not use Optional!) is suspect: Many java APIs return null to indicate no value and this will never change - map.get(), which is likely the single most important 'value returning lookup function' in the entire java ecosystem, does not return an optional. Hence, the principal advantage of Optional, which is that a mere glance at a function's type tells you whether it is guaranteed to find a result or may not find one, is a pipe dream. You can't actually do that. Because not all APIs work that way and that will never go away.
Note that more generally your code is just bad: Errors are logged and code just continues. If a situation occurs that warrants writing an error-level log event, it is exceedingly unlikely that the correct action is to just blindly continue.
What you've written is the exact opposite of what optional proseletysers want: You've introduced null in places where they should not be. Your design leads to APIs where the API as a concept strongly peddles the idea that it will necessarily return a non-null result (in an type-system way, by being in an API where any method that is designed to sometimes not return a value is typed Optional and this method is not, and in a semantic way: Presumably, given that you emit an error here, the thing this method represents (i.e. what the javadoc describes), is likely understood by the users of this API as a thing that should always return a value.
And yet, sometimes it returns null instead (along with an error in the log files, of course). This causes NullPointerExceptions.
So, one thing goes wrong, and you check the log to then find 88 different NPEs and a single log message lacking context. Every single last one of those 88 NPEs is irrelevant (they are merely the detritus caused by not just throwing when things go wrong first, which is how you're supposed to do it).
In contrast, then, perhaps this is the single best way to do this job:
return Objects.requireNonNull(somePage.someEntity().getMember());

And update the API docs accordingly. This eliminates null. Categorically. If anything is null, this causes an NPE, thus, ensuring code does not continue, and you have a log that is pointing directly at the problem. It cannot possibly produce null either (it can produce an NPE. NPEs are good! If they are thrown when an assumption the programmer made turns out not to hold up, which the LOG.error strongly suggests happened).

Yes, this.  Also somewhat relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional

While the suggestion is relevant that the code shared might not need the Optional, one thing overlooked with it is that .map(somePage::someEntity) deals implicitly over the check for someEntity being null as well.

@Naman well, Objects.requireNonNull(somePage.someEntity().getMember()) also deals with all potential null returns in a consistent way. The only thing that is missing is that entity.isMember() shall return true…
