# Is CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty() better than a null check?

Tags: java, collections, java-7, java-collections-api

Many advice to use `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)` rather then `coll != null` in the below use case also.

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)) {
    for (String str : coll) {
    }
}
```

instead of

```
if (coll != null) {
    for (String str : coll) {
    }
}
```

Is there any reason/advantage to use `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)` instead of other here? Thanks.

Comment: In this specific case, no. But sometimes you do other operations before the loop, like preparing structures.

Comment: The related question about null checks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/

Comment: @DenysSéguret, in this specific case it *does* make a difference. The `for (String str : coll)` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `coll` is `null`.

Comment: @aioobe There's a test for that. The question is about the difference between the two tests

Comment: @aioobe this is not a duplicate to "check if a collection is empty in java : Which is the best method "

Comment: @DenysSéguret, aah, sorry. You're right.

Comment: @Trying, question reopened, but I still think the answers over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152536/check-if-a-collection-is-empty-in-java-which-is-the-best-method) pretty much covers this question.

Comment: @aioobe this is little different. I am asking: is first call to `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty` then go for `for` loop better than if we simply check for null and go for `for` loop ... As @manouti stated in the answer there is some. Even tough it is very very small...

Comment: -ve voter please comment at least whats wrong.

Answer (score 9):

No real advantages here. Even if there is, it would be extremely small. It just prevents the creation of an `Iterator` and executing a branch instruction, that's all there is to it.

This small advantage occurs only when the collection is empty. The following loop:

```
for (String str : coll) {
   ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = col.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   String str = iterator.next();
   ...
}
```

When the collection is empty, the check on `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)` prevents the loop from executing. Hence no `Iterator` is created in memory and no call to `hasNext()` is done. This is at the expense to a `O(1)` call to `coll.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 9):

Decompiling reveals

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection coll) {
    return coll == null || coll.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained above it depends, what you want to test and how is your logic constructed.

Suppose your example

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)) {
  for (String str : coll) {
     System.out.println("Branch 1. Collection is not empty.");
  }
}
else {
  System.out.println("Branch 2. Collection is empty.");
}
```

In this example, we can see, that **always** Branch1 or Branch2 is executed.

If we use null expression, the result will be different if `coll` is not null but empty

```
if (coll != null) {
  for (String str : coll) {
     System.out.println("Branch1. Collection is not empty.");
  }
}
else {
  System.out.println("Branch2. Collection is empty.");
}
```

If the collection `coll` is not null but it is empty, nor Branch1 either Branch2 is executed, because the condition `coll != null` is true, but in loop `for` there is not even one pass.

Of course, `if` expression `coll != null && coll.isNotEmpty()` doing the same work as `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(coll)`.

Therefore it not advisable programming manner to use test on null in case of collections `coll != null` only. This is a case of poorly treated extreme conditions, which may be a source of unwanted result.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that the collection can still be empty, when it is not null. So, in your case it depends on your preferences what you choose.

Comment: Which changes nothing here.